О сонетах Шекспира в переводе Маршака. Опыт новых переводов
 1948 год. Первая публикация.Маршак перевел 154 
 сонета английского классика, за что в 1949 г. ему 
 была присуждена Сталинская премия.
 

Мнение из Сети: Все-таки сонеты Шекспира, какой не возьми — шедевр!
/Правильно было бы сказать "какой нИ возьми ..."./
Можно ли увидеть исключительность переводных сонетов Шекспира и считать их особым явлением  в русской литературе?
Если сравнить дословный перевод сонетов с редакцией Маршака, то можно сделать такой вывод. Шекспир интересен для русского читателя глубиной мыслей, неожиданной логикой рассуждений, но поэтичности в нем не так много. Чудо рождается при соединении мыслей английского гения с красочностью и образностью русской речи. Вернее сказать, такое возможно, но отнюдь не всегда.
Я предлагаю в качестве образца сонет 141, который не так известен, как другие. Обратите на него внимание — перед нами действительно нечто необыкновенное. Смелость и неожиданность образов поражает — они несвойственны русской поэзии, но рождены соединением двух культур.
Мои глаза в тебя не влюблены, —
Они твои пороки видят ясно.
А сердце ни одной твоей вины
Не видит и с глазами не согласно.
Ушей твоя не услаждает речь.
Твой голос, взор и рук твоих касанье,
Прельщая, не могли меня увлечь
На праздник слуха, зренья, осязанья.
И все же внешним чувствам не дано —
Ни всем пяти, ни каждому отдельно —
Уверить сердце бедное одно,
Что это рабство для него смертельно.
В своем несчастье одному я рад,
Что ты — мой грех и ты — мой вечный ад.

Вопросы такие:

Можно ли в приведенном сонете в переводе Маршака увидеть особые художественные приемы (метафоры, сравнения, композицию стиха), которые не встречались ранее и  которые удивляют своей новизной, неожиданностью?

2.Какой перевод могли бы предложить вы, что бы изменили и добавили к переводам Маршака? Интересно это было бы увидеть на конкретном примере одного или нескольких сонетов.
P. S. Сегодня 28 июня 2024 года.
Перечитала свой вопрос. Шекспир рассудочен и не поэтичен?  Нет, я не понимала Шекспира, совсем он не рассудочен. Просто его художественные образы настолько многогранны и необычны, что немногие понимают его в полной мере. Вернее сказать, хотя бы в какой-то мере. Взгляд поэта устремлен в такие глубины человеческой души, о которых мы мало задумываемся.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Я не буду ничего больше менять. Предлагаю переоткрыть вопрос, у которого есть прекрасный и совершенно уникальный ответ  и 440 просмотров за две недели.  Какие факты и цифры могут быть в теме, где нужен худ. анализ стихотворения. Причем языковой анализ!  Это ли не тема для сайта Русский язык.

141.In faith*, I do not love thee with mine eyes,
For they in thee a thousand errors note,
But 'tis my heart that loves what they despise,
Who in despite of view is pleased to dote.
Nor are mine ears with thy tongue's tune delighted,
Nor tender feeling to base touches prone,
Nor taste, nor smell, desire to be invited
To any sensual feast with thee alone;
But my five wits nor my five senses can
Dissuade one foolish heart from serving thee,
Who leaves unswayed the likeness of a man,
Thy proud heart's slave and vassal wretch** to be.
Only my plague thus far I count my gain,
That she that makes me sin awards me pain.\
Поверь, но не любовь моих ты глаз,
Для них в тебе мильон дурных примет
Но сердце признаёт иной наказ,
Не тот, что зрит, а то, что сеет бред.
Ни звонкий смех меня не утолит,
Ни нежное касанье при луне,
Ни вкус ни аромат, лишь пригласи,
На пир из чувств с тобой наедине.
Пять мудрых дум, пять чувств моих капкан
Твердят одно, что сердца стал слугой,
Ведь этот недвижимый истукан –
Раб гордости твоей, вассал-изгой.
И только хворь, что я стяжал греша,
Ту боль, она дарила не спеша.
1.From fairest creatures we desire increase,
That thereby beauty's rose might never die,
But as the riper should by time decease,
His tender heir might bear his memory:
But thou, contracted to thine own bright eyes,
Feed'st thy light's flame with self-substantial fuel,
Making a famine where abundance lies,
Thyself thy foe, to thy sweet self too cruel.
Thou that art now the world's fresh ornament
And only herald to the gaudy spring,
Within thine own bud buriest thy content,
And, tender churl, mak'st waste in niggarding:
Pity the world, or else this glutton be,
To eat the world's due, by the grave and thee.
От лучших лоз мы жаждем урожай,
Чтоб ближняя не вяла красота,
Созревший плод срезать не забывай,
Чтоб память роз рождалась от куста.
Но скован ты от блеска юных глаз,
В огне сжигая страсть, живешь смакуя,
Но ужин этот безудержный - блажь,
Себя твой враг, поел себя ликуя.
Ты тот цветок и мира свежий рант,
Глашатай зеленеющей листвы,
А вязь внутри – нетронутый талант,
Её не сбереги, а распусти.
Себя вкушать давай другим, любя,
Есть мира долг, до гроба и тебя.
130.
My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun;
Coral is far more red than her lips' red;
If snow be white, why then her breasts are dun*;
If hairs be wires**, black wires grow on her head.
I have seen roses damasked***, red and white,
But no such roses see I in her cheeks,
And in some perfumes is there more delight
Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks.
I love to hear her speak, yet well I know
That music hath a far more pleasing sound;
I grant I never saw a goddess go -
My mistress when she walks treads on the ground.
And yet, by heaven, I think my love as rare****
As any she belied with false compare.*****
My love art true as any she as rare
That knows the almost thing of beauty far.
Её блестит чернее солнца взгляд,
И алый губ бледнее, чем коралл,
Как леска кудри, скрученны подряд,
И что "как снег бела" я б не сказал.
Узоры видел шитых белым роз,
Но нет тех роз среди её ланит,
Пил в упоен'и ароматы грёз,
Но дух её дыхания манит.
От голоса оглох, хоть и внимал
Мелодиям звучащей чистоты,
Пускай земных богинь я не видал,
Она оставит на земле следы,
Пускай земных богинь не увидал,
Она протопчет на земле следы,
Любовь моя, редка, сколь часты те,
Которым честно врут о красоте.
Любовь моя честна, сколь редки те,
Которым скажут всё о красоте.
131.
Thou art as tyrannous, so as thou art,
As those whose beauties proudly make them cruel;
For well thou know'st to my dear doting heart
Thou art the fairest and most precious jewel.
Yet, in good faith, some say that thee behold
Thy face hath not the power to make love groan:
To say they err, I dare not be so bold,
Although I swear it to myself alone.
And, to be sure that is not false I swear,
A thousand groans but thinking on thy face
One on another's neck do witness bear
Thy black is fairest in my judgment's place.
In nothing art thou black save in thy deeds,
And thence this slander as I think proceeds.
Ты верно от тиранина создана,
Содеяна надменной и пустой,
И это сердца глупого вина,
Что мнит тебя редчайшей красотой.
Однако, это те, что за глаза,
Вопят, на них ты да право не гляди,
Пусть врут, а я, я не рискну сказать,
И сам себя кляну, когда один.
Но в том ещё уверен, поклянусь,
Что раз клонится к низу голова
Не смеющих в лицо твоё взглянуть,
Твой в чёрен трон, но чернота права.
Ты не хранишь черна в своих делах,
За это и оболгана в речах.
127.In the old age black was not counted fair,
Or if it were it bore not beauty's name;
But now is black beauty's successive heir,
And beauty slandered with a bastard shame:
For since each hand hath put on Nature's power,
Fairing the foul with art's false borrowed face,
Sweet beauty hath no name, no holy bower,
But is profaned, if not lives in disgrace.
Therefore my mistress' brows are raven black,
Her eyes so suited, and they mourners seem
At such who not born fair no beauty lack,
Sland'ring creation with a false esteem:
Yet so they mourn, becoming of their woe,
That every tongue says beauty should look so.
С давних пор Смоль все в роду призира-
ли, Не выносили её чистоты
Но времена тёмной силы наста
ли, Хоть обзывают блудницей лгуны:
Всё Естество грязной дланью поправ,
Лица чужих не забыв прицепить,
У красоты дом и дол отобрав,
Осквернена коль нельзя осквернить.
Вот отчего её бровь воронё-
на, И так печален лик госпожи,
Нет в красоте недостатка кто в тём-
ном Мире рождён среди одной лжи:
И всё-таки печален тёмный свет,
Коль чёрен мир, так и нечистых нет.
128.How oft,\ when thou,\ my music,\ music play'st,
2\2\3\3
Upon\ that blessed wood\ whose motion sounds
2\3\5
With thy\ sweet fingers,\ when thou gently sway'st
2\3\5
The wiry concord\ that mine ear confounds,
5\5
Do I\ envy\ those jacks\ that nimble leap
2\2\3\3
To kiss\ the tender\ inward of thy hand,
2\3\5
Whilst my\ poor lips,\ which should that\ harvest reap,
2\2\3\3
At the wood's boldness\ by thee blushing stand!
5\5
To be so tickled,\ they would change their state
5\5
And situation\ with those dancing chips,
5\5
O'er\ whom thy\ fingers walk\ with gentle gait,
2\2\3\3
Making\ dead wood\ more blest than\ living lips.
2\2\3\3
Since saucy jacks so\ happy are in this,
5\5
Give them thy fingers,\ me thy lips to kiss.
5\5
Когда\ ты здесь,\ то мело-дией опять
2\2\3\3
И клён\ и лес\ закачает такт,
2\2\5
Твои\ пальцы\ пригласят\ танцевать,
2\2\3\3(более динамично)
(Твои\пальчики\ просят танцевать)
2\3\5
"За" скрепят согласье\ все в моих ушах.
6\5\
Мне ль\ за-видно,\ изогну-лся нахал,
2\2\3\3
Поце-луев\ нежных рук атлет,
2\2\5
А я-бедный\ приз для губ\ не сорвал,
2\2\3\3
И на древе наглом\ ярко-красный след!
6\5\
Вдруг от щекотки\ они сменят стать,
5\5
И закружатся\ листочки у них,
5\5
Твои\ пальцы\ щекотят\ опадать,
2\2\3\3
Сделав\ мёртвый\ пень красней\ губ живых.
2\2\3\3!\
Каждый смертельно\ так счастлив холуй
5\5
Раз увидев пальчик, мне ж губ поцелуй.
5\5
Когда ты здесь, то под музыку опять,
В роще багряный клён качает такт,
Твои пальчики просят танцевать,
«За» скрепит в ответ, всё в моих ушах.
Мне ль за-видно, как метнул-ся нахал,
Ручки нежной, дар сорвать успев,
А я-бедный, приз для губ не пожал,
И на древе том, ярко-красный след.
К ним прикоснёшься, они сменят стать,
И закружатся листочки у них,
Твои пальцы щекотЯт опадать,
Сделав мёртвый пень красней губ живых.
Каждый смертельно так счастлив холуй,
Твой увидев пальчик, мне ж губ поцелуй.
129.Th'expense of spirit\ in a waste of shame
Is lust in action,\ and till action, lust
Is perjured, murd'rous,\ bloody, full of blame,
Savage, extreme, rude, cruel, not to trust,
Enjoyed no sooner but despisd straight,
Past reason hunted, and no sooner had
Past reason hated as a swallowed bait
On purpose laid to make the taker mad:
Mad in pursuit, and in possession(пезешин) so,
Had, having, and in quest to have, extreme,
A bliss in proof, and proved, a very woe,
Before, a joy proposed, behind, a dream.
All this the world\ well knows, yet none knows well
To shun the heaven\ that leads men to this hell.
Немощность духа в стыде лишь видна,
Коль страсть в стремленьи, и пред делом, страсть,
Гнев, смерт'убийство, хула, вот вина,
Дик, лих, груб, жёсток, поверь, всё напасть.
Жди, но неспешно, коль скоро призри,
Задний ум скорых настигнет, гонясь,
Задний ум яд источит изнутри,
Прока прокорм не доставит, гноясь:
Скорый беспечен, и рвётся стяжать,
Брать, маять, и вкушать сии плоды,
Блажен сей путь, спешишь что потерять,
Лишь искусись, и позади мечты.
Мир, зная это, всё же был бы рад
Знать как избечь пути и в этот ад.
66.Tired with all these, for restful death I cry:
As to behold desert a beggar born,
And needy nothing2 trimmed in jollity,
And purest faith unhappily forsworn,
And gilded honour shamefully misplaced,
And maiden virtue rudely strumpeted,
And right perfection wrongfully disgraced,
And strength by limping sway disabld,
And art made tongue-tied7 by authority,
And folly (doctor-like)8 controlling skill,
And simple truth miscalled simplicity9,
And captive good attending captain10 ill:
Tired with all these,\ from these would I\ be gone,
Save that to die, I leave my love alone.
О смерти лишь прошу, опустошён:
Как странник вечный средь безлюдных мест,
И цель свою забыл, шутом ряжён,
И потерял доверья лёгкий вес.
И девой нежной предан грубо был,
И славы злато мутно от стыда,
И важный кто-то мой роток прикрыл,
И скверна верно вся моя еда,
И правда, если прав любой дурак,
И честность стоит меньше, чем обман,
И если сильный избегает драк
Невольник свеж, и болен капитан:
Опустошён, я прочь сбегу, молю,
Храни по гроб любовь одну, мою.
2.When forty winters shall besiege thy brow,
And dig deep trenches\ in thy beauty's field,
Thy youth's proud livery so gazed on now
Will be a tottered weed of small worth held:
Then being asked where all thy beauty lies,
Where all the treasure of thy lusty days,
To say within thine own deep-sunken eyes
Were an all-eating shame, and thriftless praise.
How much more praise deserved thy beauty's use,
If thou couldst answer, 'This fair child of mine
Shall sum my count, and make my old excuse',
Proving his beauty by succession thine.
This were to be new made when thou art old,
And see thy blood warm when thou feel'st it cold.
Когда пол жизни тронет за чело
И сорок бразд пропашет на земле,
Твой дерзкий взгляд уж потускнел давно
И вырос сорняком на пустыре:
Где ж удалец тот, сам себе скажи,
И где здоровья клад его былой,
В колодце впалых глаз на дне лежит,
Где стыд поил тебя с лихвой порой.
Призом себя красивым награди,
Когда ты смог сказать: "Люблю моё
Дитя, что я лелеял до седин".
Что вырастил трудом, теперь твоё.
Умей сей дар принять, когда ты стар,
И кровь согреть, пока сам хлад не стал.
3.Look in thy glass* and tell the face thou viewest,
Now is the time that face should form another,
Whose fresh repair if now thou not renewest,
Thou dost beguile the world, unbless some mother**.
For where is she so fair whose uneared womb
Disdains the tillage of thy husbandry?
Or who is he so fond*** will be the tomb
Of his self-love to stop posterity?
Thou art thy mother's glass, and she in thee
Calls back the lovely April of her prime;
Despite of wrinkles, this thy golden time.
But if thou live rememb'red not to be,
Die single, and thine image dies with thee.
Так загляни в стекло, что видишь ты,
Кто тот другой, что посетил опять,
В чью плоть ты воплотил свои мечты,
Покинув их, как не родная мать.
Где та живёт, что в чреве их храня,
Лишённая забот и суеты?
А он лежит в гробу себя любя,
Не принося в твой мир свои плоды?
Стекло её, хотя внутри ты сам,
Огнём её весны пока храним,
Но через эти стёкла по часам
Уходит время золотом морщин.
Ведь если ты живешь без мысли быть,
Умри один, и дай тебя забыть.
4.Unthrifty loveliness, why dost thou spend
Upon thyself thy beauty's legacy?
Nature's bequest gives nothing, but doth lend,
And being frank she lends to those are free:
Then, beauteous niggard, why dost thou abuse
The bounteous largess given thee to give?
Profitless usurer, why dost thou use
So great a sum of sums, yet canst not live?
For having traffic with thyself alone,
Thou of thyself thy sweet self dost deceive:
Then how, when Nature calls thee to be gone,
What cceptable audit canst thou leave?
Thy unused beauty must be tombed with thee,
Which usd lives th'executor to be.\
Любитель расточать, что ж тратишь дни
Лишь на себя наследства юной стати?
Природой обделен, тогда займи,
Она подаст и ещё даром, кстати:
Затем, прекрасный жмот, зачем хулишь,
За щедрость данную тебе давать?
Пусть пользу выгод всех и уследишь,
Кому исхода аудит считать?
Величье суммы сумм, но мощь в карман?
Коль всё вбирать в себя лишь одного,
Весь ты в себе, и сладок твой обман:
Но как Природе в лоно звать, кого?
Вся непригодна стать в гробу с тобой,
Коль ты тюремщик над своей душой**.
Я решил писать пояснения к переводам:
*beauty - handsome, статный, стать.
**th'executor(душеприказчик, надсмотрщик)=тюремщик над душой.
Переставлена строка 12 на место 8.
5.Those hours that with gentle work did frame
The lovely gaze where every eye doth dwell
Will play the tyrants to the very same,
And that unfair which fairly doth excel;
For never-resting time leads summer on
To hideous winter and confounds him there,
Sap checked with frost and lusty leaves quite gone,
Beauty o'ersnowed and bareness every where:
Then were not summer's distillation left
A liquid prisoner pent in walls of glass,
Beauty's effect with beauty were bereft,
Nor it nor no remembrance what it was.
But flowers distilled, though they with winter meet,
Leese but their show; their substance still lives sweet.
Часы забот кроят узоры рам,
Прядут приют любви и взгляда лиц,
Но в чистоте усердия тиран,
Ведь всё нечисто если, вне границ.
Без отдыха трудиться в летний день,
Не отвратит смешения зимой,
Уж сок остыл и стар бесстрастный пень,
Но красоте под снегом как, ногой:
Когда покинет лета чистота,
Хрустальный пленник ляжет под стекло,
Раз за границей то, не красота,
Ни красоты, ни памяти её.
Пусть чист цветок и встретится с зимой,
Снег не острог, доколь внутри живой.
Пусть чист цветок и встретился зимой,
Не будь так строг, пока внутри живой.
Стих содержит три парадокса, по одному в каждой строфе:
1)"Но в чистоте усердия тиран,\Ведь всё нечисто если, вне границ."(Will play the tyrants to the very same,\And that unfair which fairly doth excel;) Когда стремишься к чистоте формы, попадаешь в парадоксальную ситуацию, что всё что за рамками формы, к которой стремишься, ей не является, а значит НЕЧИСТО по отношению к ней.
2)"Но красоте под снегом как, ногой:"(Beauty o'ersnowed and bareness every where: - дословно, "красота под снегом и полностью обнажена") - очищение формы красоты делает её слишком зависимой и тепличной. Банально, растения культурные, приносящие при хороших условиях богатые урожаи не способны существовать рядом с сорняками, которые их могут "забить". То есть люди стремящиеся к чистоте внутренней красоты становятся неприспособленными к грубостям реального мира и в итоге могут замкнуться в себе, "зазвездиться", дистанцироваться, и тому подобное, чтобы не воспринимать грубость мира.
3)"Раз за границей то, не красота," - Красота не может быть ограничена рамками, нельзя поместить красоту, которой восторгался художник в некое пространства. Красивая картина - это вовсе не красота, а окно в мир красоты, который видел художник, когда рисовал картину вдохновившись красотой мира, красота в банке, сама по себе красотой не являющаяся. Человек смотрит на колбы с очищенной красотой, но если в у него нет возможность видеть естественную красоту, то в нём не будет этой красоты, и для него картина или другая колба с красотой не будут этим окном.
6.Then let not winter's ragged hand deface
In thee thy summer ere thou be distilled:
Make sweet some vial; treasure thou some place
With beauty's treasure ere it be self-killed:
That use is not forbidden usury
Which happies those that pay the willing loan;
That's for thyself to breed another thee,
Or ten times happier be it ten for one;
Ten times thyself were happier than thou art,
If ten of thine ten times refigured thee:
Then what could death do if thou shouldst depart,
Leaving thee living in posterity?
Be not self-willed, for thou art much too fair
To be death's conquest and make worms thine heir.
Когда б избег ты лап зимы косой,
И лето в сердце тёплое храня,
Пустой флакон прибережёт постой*
Твоей красы, теперь убей себя*****:
То не в заклад не верь ты чудесам.
Немногое получишь с пустоты;
Других тебя родишь, но вот ты сам,
Счастливей сто крат, но лишь, чем ты.
Счастливей, в десять раз, чем мог создать****,
И десять раз дести в тебе одном,
Ведь кто уйдет**, раз нужно отступать,
Живущее тебя живёт потом?
Не обожай себя, твой дар**** важней,
Чем смертью пав, быть домом для червей****.
*ПостОй - временное место для стоянки, ночёвки.
**Уйдёт - в оригинале было "кто умрёт", но смысл не меняется - живущее "тебя" уйдет и останется жить.
***Стать домом для червей - в оригинале "сделать червей своими наследниками".
****Создат, твой дар - art, искусство, ремесло, творческое начало.
*****"убей себя" - self-killed, сразу скажу, что не стоит путать с физическим САМоубийством, речь идёт о некой практике духовной смерти, которая есть и в христианстве и других религиях, связанная с возрождением некого истинного воплощения, " смертью умрешь"(Бытие). То есть, если селф-килд - это некая смерть с последующим духовным перерождением, то "смертию пав, быть домом для червей" - это противоположное духовное падение, без возрождение, более близкое к физической смерти. В общем, сложный стих, наверное, самый сложный и тяжёлый для понимания на данный момент)
7.Lo in the orient when the gracious light
Lifts up his burning head, each under eye
Doth homage to his new-appearing sight,
Serving with looks his sacred majesty;
And having climbed the steep-up heavenly hill,
Resembling strong youth in his middle age,
Yet mortal looks adore his beauty still,
Attending on his golden pilgrimage:
But when from highmost pitch, with weary car,
Like feeble age he reeleth from the day,
The eyes (fore duteous) now converted are
From his low tract and look another way:
So thou, thyself outgoing in thy noon,
Unlooked on diest unless thou get a son.
О погляди зардел грации свет,
Высит горящий вид выше очей,
Каждый принять готов новый обет,
Службу следя его мощи лучей.
Так поднимаясь ввысь на небеса
Юный и нежный лик входит в зенит,
И каждый смертный взор эта краса
Тем золотым путём о-осенит.
Но в самой вышине и всякий раз
Старый возница вдруг хочет уснуть,
И поворотит вспять свой ясный глаз,
Где каждый должён зреть дня новый путь:
Так ты, как твой закат придёт всего,
Не видишь смерть, лишь сына твоего.
8.Music to hear, why hear'st thou music sadly?
Sweets with sweets war not, joy delights in joy:
Why lov'st thou that which thou receiv'st not gladly,
Or else receiv'st with pleasure thine annoy?
If the true concord of well-tund sounds,
By unions married, do offend thine ear,
They do but sweetly chide thee, who confounds
In singleness the parts that thou shouldst bear;
Mark how one string, sweet husband to another,
Strikes each in each by mutual ordering;
Resembling sire, and child, and happy mother,
Who all in one, one pleasing note do sing;
Whose speechless song being many, seeming one,
Sings this to thee, 'Thou single wilt prove none.'
Слышишь мотив, отчего так грустно?
Сладкое на сладком только 'ведь вкусней:
Если ты любишь, отчего так пусто,
Или раздражает, делая больней?
Если согласье, то 'и звук отличный
Н'к обетам счастья остаешься глух,
Легкие уколы 'их будут органичны,
Части одного приласкают слух;
Муж другой 'и точка, 'ты возьми за строчку,
Части 'к 'части ордена создают уют;
Словно 'снова вместе царь, мать и сыночек.
Все они в 'тебе одном сладостно поют.
Вместе безмолвья кажутся одним,
Но когда поёшь одно ты неразделим.
Получилось ну очень странно).
9.Is it for fear to wet a widow's eye
That thou consum'st thyself in single life?
Ah! if thou issueless shalt hap to die,
The world will wail thee like a makeless wife;
The world will be thy widow and still weep,
That thou no form of thee hast left behind,
When every private widow well may keep,
By children's eyes, her husband's shape in mind:
Look what an unthrift in the world doth spend
Shifts but his place, for still the world enjoys it,
But beauty's waste hath in the world an end,
And kept unused the user so destroys it:
No love toward others in that bosom sits
That on himself such murd'rous shame commits.
От страха снова влажные глаза
Твоей вдовы, что пожираешь жизнь?
Ах! как бездарно смерть вдруг подошла,
Мир по тебе свой вой начёт служить;
Мир по тебе вдовой твоей скорбит,
Что не оставил от тебя следа,
Который вдова каждая хранит
В глазах детей и муже от ума:
Смотри же, как сей мир не прихотлив,
Сменяет часть, чтоб продолжать дышать
Лишь радостью и красоты прилив,
Непролитой тобой, слезами ждать:
Любви к иному нет в груди когда,
Убивший не сгорает со стыда.
В конце получилось немного не то)
Смотри же, как сей мир неизменим,
Растратил кто-то, он же смог впитать,
Но красотой он от конца храним,
И расточить её, мир разрушать:
Любви к иному нет в груди когда,
Убивший не сгорает со стыда.
Ну, будет лишний куплет?
10.For shame deny that thou bear'st love to any,
Who for thyself art so unprovident.
Grant, if thou wilt, thou art beloved of many,
But that thou none lov'st is most evident;
For thou art so possess'd with murd'rous hate,
That 'gainst thyself thou stick'st not to conspire,
Seeking that beauteous roof to ruinate
Which to repair should be thy chief desire:
O change thy thought, that I may change my mind!
Shall hate be fairer lodged than gentle love?
Be as thy presence is, gracious and kind,
Or to thyself at least kind-hearted prove:
Make thee another self, for love of me,
That beauty still may live in thine or thee.
Чтоб стыд отъять твой от любви к таким,
Кто твоего не крепит ремесла,
Дари, коль хочешь, ты любовь любым,
Но не любовь, когда она слепа;
Ведь дар твой одержимый местью той,
Что дар скрывая, не дает дышать,
Найди, разбей же склянку с красотой,
И излечи желание мечтать:
Так измени твой ум, μετάνοια!
Ведь месть не изместит любовью ум?
Почувствуй, что в тебе есть грация,
И для себя cogito, ergo sum:
Создай себе иного милым мне,
Но красотой живи в твоём, в тебе.
11.As fast as thou shalt wane, so fast thou grow'st
In one of thine, from that which thou departest,
And that fresh blood which youngly thou bestow'st
Thou mayst call thine, when thou from youth convertest:
Herein lives wisdom, beauty, and increase,
Without this, folly, age, and cold decay:
If all were minded so, the times should cease,
And threescore year would make the world away.
Let those whom Nature hath not made for store,
Harsh, featureless, and rude, barrenly perish:
Look whom she best endowed she gave the more;
Which bounteous gift thou shouldst in bounty cherish:
She carved thee for her seal, and meant thereby,
Thou shouldst print more, not let that copy die.
Ты меньше с тем, чем глубже прорастёшь,
В одном твоём, в ком от тебя лишь часть,
Ты крови свежей юность отдаёшь,
Теперь он твой, когда вмещаясь всласть:
Живут в нём мудрость, красота и рост,
А если нет, дурь, возраст и урод:
Коль время стало и пролёг погост,
Три двадцать лет и кончен мира ход.
Дай тем, кто был Природой обделён,
Быть безобразным, пустоцветом, злым:
Ищи тех, в ком приют души её,
Кто дар лелея, делает твоим:
Она тебя пометила рождать,
Так размножай плодя её печать.
Злой сонет, ну вот так)
12.When I do count the clock* that tells the time,
And see the brave day sunk in hideous night,
When I behold the violet past prime,
And sable curls all siluer'd ore with white,
When lofty trees I see barren of leaves,
Which erst from heat did canopy the herd,
And summer's green all girded up in sheaves
Borne on the bier with white and bristly beard:
Then of thy beauty do I question make
That thou among the wastes of time must go,
Since sweets and beauties do themselves forsake,
And die as fast as they see others grow,
And nothing 'gainst Time's scythe can make defence
Save breed to brave him when he takes thee hence.
Когда, сочту я колокола бой,
Взгляну во тьму, где храбрый тонет день,
Когда фиал увянет молодой,
Лишь блеск кудрей в серебряной руде,
Когда деревьев кроны без листа,
Что в летний зной могли укрыть стада,
Средь нив зелёных кончена страда,
На саван дрог спадает борода:
Так вот, мой милый, чем тревожусь я,
Не будь средь тех, чей скорбный час пробил,
Но как тебя отвергнет красота,
Умри, пока млад, кто тебе так мил,
Раз Времени безжалостна коса,
Храни в потомке храбрость до конца.
Clock - от французского "клош", колокол, to count the clock - считать удары колокола, то есть. «Не спрашивай, по ком звонит колокол, он звонит по тебе».
Короче передрал у Финкеля "дрог свисает борода".
14.Not from the stars do I my judgment pluck,
And yet methinks I have astronomy,
But not to tell of good or evil luck,
Of plagues, of dearths, or seasons' quality;
Nor can I fortune to brief minutes tell,
Pointing to each his thunder, rain and wind,
Or say with princes if it shall go well
By oft predict that I in heaven find:
But from thine eyes my knowledge I derive,
And, constant stars*, in them I read such art
As truth and beauty shall together thrive
If from thy self to store thou wouldst convert*:
Or else of thee this I prognosticate,
Thy end is truth's and beauty's doom and date.
По звёздам не считая перемен,
Всё мнится мне, я будто астроном,
Но не такой, кто знает о судьбе,
Предскажет смерть или худой сезон;
Ни точный час не укажу громам,
Дождю и направлению ветров,
Небес благословление не дам,
Я господам из титульных домов:
Но вижу звёздный свет в твоих очах,
И точно знаю правду красоты,
Что, распускаясь, нежится в лучах,
И от себя к тебе обра́щен ты:
Или напротив, видя в них разлад,
Конец красы сочту и твой распад.
Convert - "a change or turn from one religion to another."
15.When I consider every thing that grows
Holds in perfection but a little moment,
That this huge stage presenteth nought but shows
Whereon the stars in secret influence comment;
When I perceive that men as plants increase,
Cheerd and checked even by the selfsame sky,
Vaunt in their youthful sap, at height decrease,
And wear their brave state out of memory:
Then the conceit of this inconstant stay
Sets you most rich in youth before my sight,
Where wasteful Time debateth with Decay
To change your day of youth to sullied night,
And all in war with Time for love of you,
As he takes from you, I ingraft you new.
Я примечаю, хоть всё и растёт,
Спеша любить, как все любить спешим,
На краткий миг жемчужный небосвод
Так совершенен и недостижим;
Я вижу, люди как побеги лоз
Стремятся к звёздам близким, в небеса,
Высоки, если полны юных грёз,
И рядом, если память их жива:
Своей тщеславной перемене рад,
Всяк смертный, споря, Время расточит,
Направит луч в космический Распад,
Плевочек ясный в вечный мрак ночи,
И сломлен если в схватке человек,
Любовью новый к вам привью побег.
"Значит — кто-то называет эти плевочки жемчужиной?"
Точность немного пострадала, но мне кажется, я уловил суть. И ещё заметил, что почти потратил лимит в 30 000 знаков в ответе.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Плюс я вам давно поставил, добавил бы ещё несколько. Всё пока не прочитал, но первая строфа очень понравилась!

Я имел в виду 130-й сонет, строфу из которого я пытался перевести в другом вопросе Sharon... А у вас почему-то стоит 140.

Чем эти стихи, отмеченные как "принятый ответ", отвечают на вопрос? Какой-то произвол на форуме.

@Третийглаз у нас тут поэтический клуб.

короче harvest rip - это смертельная жатва, а jack - это тыквенная голова на праздник урожая.

Мне кажется, пора заканчивать с обсуждением Шекспира... уже давно стало понятно, что переводы наших предшественников далеко не идеальны и что считать их особым явлением нельзя, хотя я бы и не стал так резко отзываться о них, как Буратино, поскольку переводчики работали в совсем других условиях, сейчас про любое непонятное можно разузнать за пять секунд, а им приходилось выкручиваться, выдумывать, советоваться... поправьте, если я неправильно понял суть темы.

@Арчи Для меня поиск ошибок у Маршака и других - второстепенная цель, мне любопытнее понять, что представляют собой сонеты на самом деле.

@Буратино Я  с интересом слежу за вашим творчеством, радуюсь вашим удачам и находкам.  Пояснение к переводам – это весьма разумно.

@Sharon я понял, что это магия или алхимия, трансмутация, метаморфоза, когда вещи и сущности переходят из одних в другие сохраняя некую первоначальную идею, поэтому я по сути восстанавливаю этот первообраз, и по нему подбираю слова, вот в первом сонете было слово АРТ,  "thou that art", я перевёл как "цветок" - "ты тот цветок", и в следующих сонетах тоже появляется цветок в виде сорняка, или тут, в виде цветка под снегом. В прошлом сонете закончилось о том, что не нужно быть тюремщиком над душой, в этом эта тема получает развитие - тюрьма или стеклянный гроб, для цветка


хрустального(текучего) пленника. И кроме того, мне кажется, что я достраиваю и доделываю некоторые моменты, которые Ш не докрутил, сделав их слишком замудрёными в виде: And that unfair which fairly doth excel; И некрасиво если, вне границ. - Beauty's effect with beauty were bereft, - Что за границей, то не красота. И тут уже видно, что у него чистота переходит в красоту и наоборот, так же как в сонете 127.


Есть слова, которые никаким образом не вписываются в текст, что бы они ни значили. Поэтому не хочу червей!))  // А вы можете пересказать идею текста понятным языком, то есть к чему призывает себя (в лице Ты) Шекспир? Как правильно жить?  Ведь именно это захочет понять читатель нового перевода.

@Sharon ... ну как объяснить, не хотите червей)... Во-первых, я не думаю, что Шекспир где-то говорит "как правильно жить", он размышляется о жизни и месте человека в мире, возможно новом мире, мире без магии, и постоянно наталкивается на парадоксы: Ты-красивый цветок, но если любуешься своей красотой лишь сам, не показывая её миру, то красота себя жестока к тебе. Так любуясь цветок завянет и твой куст превратиться в сорняк, сможешь ли ты любоваться сорняком? И кто вообще такой ты, тот кто любуется цветком себя? как увидеть тебя? в отражении? Кто тот другой в отражении? Тот ты каким ты о ком

мечтал, или другой, нежданный гость? Тот кто убьёт тебя и займет твоё место пока тебя в гробу будут есть черви? Ну этот сонет вообще чистый Гамлет, как и 3. Быть или не быть? Шекспир не может выбрать за Гамлета "как правильно жить". Он может рассказать некую историю, о Гамлете.

А у Маршака все понятно. Пока ты совершенный цветок, то собери с себя нектар в некий флакон. То есть возьми лучшее в себе и воплоти в жизнь в виде своего творчества, которое ты оставишь людям. И это у него обращение к каждому человеку, к его духовному Я.  Обычно сонеты делят на тематические группы, при этом сонеты 1 - 26  называют "Воспевание друга".  Пусть это будет воспеванием духовного Я.  Но чем-то они отличаются, есть ли в них развитие  идеи?  Или это разные художественные образы, а идея одна та же?

У Маршака в 5 сонете, например, полностью нет парадоксов. То есть Ш не просто так делает некие утверждения, а на основе неких наблюдений, наблюдение->рассуждение->вывод или парадокс. А Маршак просто наблюдение-суждение. То есть Ш пишет, если стремиться к чистоте очищая красоту, он становится обнаженной и беззащитной перед холодом, который придёт, например. А Маршак просто пишет: придёт зима, а розы всё равно пахнут. Почему? Просто так, без объяснения того, как он пришёл к таким умозаключениям. Маршак может передать отношение, суждение, но не может построить логическую цепочку размышлений о.

И когда в 7 Ш говоря о солнце, сам находится в позиции солнца, то Маршак пишет с позиции людей смотрящих на солнце, воспринимающих солнца, но не способных постичь того искусства или закона, которому солнце следует. Поэтому Маршак вынужден называть солнце солнцем, а Ш ни разу не называет божество, но за счёт сторонних проявлений добивается его божественности. Ш говорит о боге, его чудесном проявлении, чуде, творит чудо, когда Маршак говорит "бог" и делает так... попадает в ловушку типичной пропаганды ценностей, навязывая.

6 сонет сравните, в Маршака ну просто все весело и беззаботно, при том как у Ш это "убей себя", трагедия. У Маршака же есть только комедия и весьма ограниченная драма, эмоциональная, а трагедии нет. У Финкеля в этом плане, есть моменты трагизма, а у Чайковского иногда попадаются парадоксы, но по-своему объяснённые.

"Когда же солнце завершает круг
И катится устало на закат," - вот Маршак, уже грубая неточность, у Ш, когда солнце находится в высшей точке происходит момент надлома и поворота взора смотрящих, а вовсе не когда солнце "завершает круг", усталость в самом верху. Тоже у Финкеля: "Но в час, когда оно, закончив путь,
Расставшись с днем, свергается в закат,"  Вот у Чайковского в этом плане точнее. И это в самом деле так, все почитают только когда идёт восхождение, но чем выше, тем мельчайшая ошибка может отворотить заворожённых видом. У Ш есть эта точность. И эта точность момента и есть красота.

Хотя, конечно, Маршак смог в строку впихнуть "колесница", я не смог) не лезла никак, обошёлся возницей) зато я добавил в момент как солнце разворачивая направление своего взгляда тем самым разворачивает взгляды смотрящих. То есть происходит полный разворот мизансцены. Сначала они смотрели на солнце, а теперь они смотря то, куда смотрит солнце. Моя вольность) Но мне кажется это даже дополняет рассказ, потому что "ты видишь сына", так же как солнце смотрит в сторону нового рассвета.

"Обычно сонеты делят на тематические группы, при этом сонеты 1 - 26 называют "Воспевание друга". Пусть это будет воспеванием духовного Я. Но чем-то они отличаются, есть ли в них развитие идеи? Или это разные художественные образы, а идея одна та же?" - в Маршака и Чайковского практически одна и та же: потомство рожай, сына, сына надо, быстрее...) ты так красив, тебе нельзя умирать, рожай детей, детей) 4 сонет, в котором вообще этого нет: "Но, давши плод, останется живой."Ч"Невоплощенный, будет погребен!"М"Не пущена тобою в оборот,
Краса твоя без пользы пропадет."Ф,тут вообще "пущена в оборот"

Ох уж этот речевой "оборот") не красиво.

Хотя, может я тоже не совсем так как было перевёл 3 сонет. Может хотелось трагедии) хотя вот это die single  - тоже не особо весёлое заявление. Так что мне кажется я всё-таки отразил сложность отношений, и там также говориться мать в тебе, речь не о какой-то отдельной женщине... То есть в лоб сводить всё к тому, что давай мол размножайся, сына давай, жену ищи, девственницу) - это слишком примитивизировать проблематику. "Thou art thy mother's glass, and she in thee" твоё искусство материнское отражение, и она в тебе.

"Despite of wrinkles, this thy golden time." - 3, несмотря на морщины это твоё золотое время. То есть "другу" эээ ну уже не 20-25 лет). То есть в этих сонетах жизнь человека весьма зрелого, который как солнце находится в зените и переживает надлом своего восхождения. Я так это вижу. Ну и скорее всего он себе самому просто стихи писал, себе о себе самом.

Я восхищаюсь вашими работами и очень надеюсь  на совершенный результат в итоге)

@Sharon Владимира Семёныча будете слушать?)

я думала – настоящего! // Высоцкий и Шекспир – это что-то) Надо подумать... Неужели они пересекаются? Спасибо! До сонета 27 Шекспир должен прославлять друга, а он его как будто уже обличает.

@Sharon Почему обличает?) в 13 он вообще к какой-то даме обращается и на вы, хоть и заканчивает про сына, но такое ощущение, что это как наполовину из Гамлета, обращение отца Гамлета к его матери, до рождения Гамлета, там что-то про то, что дом(клан) сопротивляется неким изменениям в мире.

А где ваш сонет 12?   Вы приводите только построчный перевод?

То есть червей не хотите, а белых и небритых хотите?

А что на меня смотреть) У вас 400 читателей в теме. Так он у вас есть?

Напишу всё-таки еще пару слов.  // Досмотрела передачу ЖЗЛ, гостями были И. Шайтанов и А. Минкин (строгий такой моралист). Поговорили о серьёзных вещах, немного посмеялись, не без этого.  Запомнилось вот что (вывод). (1) Шекспир как бы создал современный англ. язык (как Пушкин у нас) —около 3 тысяч своих новых слов. Изучая только  разговорный вариант, нельзя  знать англ. язык по-настоящему. Читайте Шекспира! (2) Шекспир был значимым явлением в англ. и мировой культуре, ознаменовал переход к Новому времени. Он создал целую галерею лиц и характеров, но свое лицо, вероятно, скрыл от нас.

Я желаю вам (Тhee)  успехов в работе, если Шекспир все еще увлекает вас.

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/u5_Y_duDdkQgMA - 12 новый.

В общем, восторг! Почему-то мне очень хотелось увидеть сонет 12 в вашем переводе – мне казалось, что там много особенных слов. Но это лучше того, что я ожидала и хотела. В переводе  есть  волнующая глубина Шекспира:  кисть  талантливого художника – и полет души, взгляд со стороны.  Краски  в первой части  очень хороши – уже здесь чувств через край.  Но  какая удивительная мысль: умри раньше, чем покинет тебя красота. Я не вижу этого в переводах Маршака  или еще где-то. «Твой рыцарь выше всех похвал, всех слов, что знает разум мой!»  Это цитата, но я иногда себя цитирую)

Про исполнение я вам на почту напишу, у меня там свои фантазии.

Сонет 14. Ах, ах, теперь все чудесно.  Я не зря сравниваю литературу с живописью: чуть-чуть поправлены краски, и стих будто оживает. // А ударение никак нельзя изменить?)

Теперь детали...По звёздам не считая перемен,
Всё мнится мне, я будто астроном,  //Могут быть вопросы к дееприч. обороту.  Галлицизм. Тогда так?   По звёздам не считаю перемен,
Но мнится мне, я будто астроном,

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/I1DBM9zfcBgfIA - 14. Не знаю, что такое галлицизм)

Спасибо!  Нравится, о-очень!  Будет среди моих любимых.   // Кстати, я не видела этого сообщения, не шлют уведомление.  // Честно говоря, мне такой галлицизм нравится, он такой поэтичный, жаль править, но вы сами решите. Я вам чуть позже  пришлю информацию на почту по грамматике.

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/0Fpgzi9LWKcG4g - 12 допилил.

Сонет 15. Интересный получился перевод, мне нравится!  О лимите  Может,  вам дать ответ  на другой мой вопрос, там как раз участники предлагали свои переводы.  Можно сонет 15 записать прямо сейчас  и туда  тоже.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480832/Сонеты-Шекспира-в-переводе-Маршака-в-чем-своеобразие-художественных-средств-выр

@Sharon https://disk.yandex.ru/d/8DAI0NRYsqXAIQ -15, музыку спёр у Фурье ОП 50 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQDoN40-_C4

ОТЗЫВ ОТ 20.06.2024
Спасибо! И за живой звук в особенности. Мне вообще кажется, что стихи нужно именно петь, а не декламировать. Ну и в виде графики они все-таки не то.
В общем, восторг!  До меня наконец дошел смысл этого цикла сонетов. Не было никакого прекрасного друга!  Ты — это обращение к себе, к каждому человеку. Жизнь скоротечна: где искать ее смысл, как достойно ею распорядиться? Такие мысли казались новыми современникам Шекспира, волновали и воодушевляли их.  Неудивительно, что сонеты казались сладкими, как сахар.  Это тоже яркие чувства, если людям нужны именно чувства.
И плохую услугу оказали критики тем, что выдумали  реального адресата сонетов.  Разумеется, ренессансная мужская дружба, даже основанная на высоких идеалах, не вызовет большого сочувствия  у читателей. Именно поэтому тематика этих сонетов не особенно волновала меня. Но сейчас они кажутся мне прекрасными, а в вашей трактовке особенно. Конечно, надо привыкнуть к метафорам Шекспира,  иногда они необычны на слух. Но в то же время это истинный голос эпохи.
У вопроса большое количество просмотров,  люди читают и, надеюсь, слушают  вас.  Поэтому хорошо, что вы указываете  тексты, пояснения  и ссылки на записи. Спасибо.
Из комментариев
ОБСУЖДЕНИЕ ПОЭТИКИ ШЕКСПИРА (на примере конкретного перевода сонетов 1, 141, 130)
ТРУДНОСТИ ПЕРЕВОДА (Как уложить английскую речь того времени в современную русскую грамматику?)
—  Мне нравятся рифмованные переводы зарубежной поэзии. Рифма придает стиху особое звучание, ее строгий канон важен для восприятия текста. Но для сонетов Шекспира это оказалось сложной задачей — изысканная речь английского классика неохотно укладывается в русскую рифму, что-то непременно теряется. Но ваш вариант, несомненно, удачен! Вам удалось совместить магию шекспировских строк и поэтичность русской речи. Спасибо!
—  Тоже что ли попереводить Шекспира, а то мне кажется у Маршака, ну очень вольный перевод). Читал так же ещё два других перевода, и, мне кажется у меня(похвалю себя) есть очень удачные моменты как в самом начале - in faith=поверь(двусложное с корнем вера), так и моменты занятных фонетических сочетаний с одновременной образностью - "пир телесных яств", что, кстати говоря, тоже практически совпадает с написанным в оригинале.
И вот это мне ещё нравится, на противопоставлении - вассал в изгнан'и, vassal wretch -вассал + изгой, изгнанник. "vassal wretch - порабощенное низкое существо. Культурная традиция быть рабом и вассалом для любовницы была особо популярна в Средневековье." - пишут так, однако дословный перевод не менее интересен и сохраняет смысл. То есть практически дословный перевод вышел и в ритмику ложится. to dote - и вот это слово, я почитал, его верно было бы перевести именно так - бред, бредить, вот у Финкеля он верно переведено, а в двух других смысл потерян - "Тобою сердце бредит беспрестанно."
То есть мне кажется, что при переводе стиха, важно сохранить ритм, ритмические совпадения и именно те слова, которые были в оригинале, иначе это уже другой стих. Маршак уходи в размышления о боге, которых в стихе нет совершенно, вообще вот это "пять чувств" - это скорее алхимия или эзотерика, потому что там пять это сакральное число - "Известно пятикратное деление мира, существуют 5 элементов мироздания, 5 классов животных, 5 органов чувств у человека, 5 внутренних органов, 5 страстей" вроде того. Два жды пять никто не смог перевести)
Проблема переводов даже не в рифме, а в том, что русские слова слишком длинные, а английские - короткие, вот есть слово wits - вот как его перевести, мало того, что оно непереводимое, так ещё и короткое. В итоге ни Маршак, ни Чайковский его вообще не переводят, наиболее близкий в этом плане перевод Финкеля, но концовка подкачала. Финкель перевод как "разум" и тут же теряет "пять", потому что в ритм уже не влезает.
— Конечно, переводите! Прекрасно! Это мое самое первое впечатление. Я только пробежала стих глазами и сразу поняла — это что-то. Дух шекспировской эпохи, необычная лексика в узнаваемых речевых оборотах… Здесь нет стилизации под современность, как у Маршака , и это тоже необычно, удивительно. Такой особенный шарм!
К тому же вы хорошо разбираетесь в языкознании, кто из переводчиков с вами сравниться? Честно говоря, мне ни один перевод не нравится. Да и все сонеты (в русских переводах) шедеврами не назовешь. А вот у самого Шекспира, возможно, есть что-нибудь мало изученное, но достойное внимания.
—  Я всего лишь переводил, а стихи шекспировские, не мои. Мне кстати сонеты Шекспира не особо и нравятся, возможно из-за не лучшего перевода. Мне Вийон нравится, его переводы куда лучше. Но этот сонет в оригинале оказался действительно интереснее, чем его переведённые аналоги. Ну и да. они какие-то слишком простые что ли, разговорные, а тут важна игра слов, текст должен быть и ритмичным, но не слишком простым. На прозе пока не пишу, может напишу)
— Про Маршака еще скажу, у него другое… Под влиянием Шекспира он создает новую поэтику. Мои глаза в тебя не влюблены… Первая фраза выглядит очень смелой метафорой, кто из русских поэтов так сказал бы! Недостатки внешности тоже пороками не назовут. Получается такая театральность метафорической пьесы. А новизна приманчива… Нравится то, что волнует воображение. Удачи вам! А это интересная статья про переводы vk.com/wall-24831014_393294
Еще любопытно: poembook.ru/contest/658/poem/38130 "Однажды мне довелось познакомиться со студенткой-итальянкой из Рима. Она училась на филологическом факультете Университета в Риме. Когда я спросила ее, нравятся ли ей стихи Шекспира, она удивилась:” Разве Шекспир писал стихи?!” И показала мне свой учебник, где все произведения Шекспира представляли из себя построчный перевод, на мой взгляд, стихов. Я была на распутье – считать Шекспира писателем или поэтом?"
Проверьте, пожалуйста, вторую строфу, я не совсем понимаю грамматику, Вы уверены, что там должна быть форма "ни даже встреч"? Переводчик дает дословный перевод: Ни вкус, ни обоняние не вызывают желания быть приглашенным На любой чувственный праздник с тобой наедине". // А Маршак здесь ловко ушел в метафоры, подальше от чувственных образов))
— Я подумаю), там есть сложные моменты)
— Меня смутил Р. п. У вас есть еще сонет 1?! Ваш текст мне нравится, но я смысл сонета не очень понимаю, в том числе у Маршака. Кому он посвящен? Прекрасному юноше?
— Мне кажется, посвящены "тебе") На "ты" можно обращаться к другому, а можно к себе.
— В сонете 1 Шекспир очень рассудочен и поучителен, а мне нравится влюбленный Шекспир. Чувства вызывают сочувствие)) Сонеты с 127-го по 154-й посвящены смуглой леди?
— Не знаю про леди, может быть) в 1 сонете речь идет о том, что мир - это некий сад, и что в этом саду есть растения или создания, которые цветут, но их цветение не бесконечно и должно превращаться в плоды, как мне кажется, которые нужно срывать, чтобы появлялись новые цветы. Потом говориться о неком человеке, который в силу возраста, хочет оставаться цветком, не принося плодов, и что его нежный возраст делает его врагом своему долгу кормить людей своими плодами, а не только цвести, пытаясь сохранить свою увядающую красоту. Мне кажется так. Ну типа "Пустоцвет"
—  Много правите… Стих капризен, в нем есть то, что подсказано интуицией. Другими словами, начальное вдохновение души. Некоторые строки будто приходят к нам из будущего в готовом виде. Исправляя, можно потерять… Вы не спешите, подумайте еще. Сравните с авторским текстом свой начальный вариант, от него нежелательно далеко уходить. Ну мне так кажется…
— "Вы не спешите, подумайте еще." - а мне кажется именно так, что "страсть быть приглашённым" противопоставлена всем остальным наслаждениям которые приписывались времяпрепровождению с "прекрасной дамой", то есть сонет про то, что она не является "прекрасной" для него, в классическом смысле, но при этом он обуян страстью и не может перестать её желать и становится рабом этого желания. И ни его стороны разума, ни чувства воспитанные на восприятии прекрасного не могут заставить его "сердце" чувствовать то, что оно чувствует. В остальных переводах не так это подается, кстати говоря.
Точнее у чайковского вообще этого нет, а у Финкеля и Маршака смысл исправлен на противоположный, но тогда не ясно, в чём же "рабство" и "подчинение" этой особе у лирического героя. То есть по логике не понятно, почему так. В английском просто так запятые не ставятся, мне кажется, то есть тут запятая в сложносочинённом, никаких намёков на подчиненность тут нет в предложении, и фраза про "страсть быть приглашённым" не связана с текстом про "Ни то, ни то", кроме, разве как на противопоставление.
То есть стих, это такая конструкция, где есть переклички между частями в разных строфах, а не только в одной фразе какая-то связь. В первой строфе он пишет про "бред"( дот - иррациональные порывы), противопоставляя его более понятным и оценочным чувственным восприятиям(то есть у нас слово "чувство" имеет два смысла - внешние чувства, сенсорика, и внутренние переживания, а в английском переживания относятся к "сердцу", а не к сенсорике пяти). И во второй строфе "бред" перекликается со "страстным желанием" - дезире или дезая.
Тем самым опять противопоставление, но наоборот "ни то, ни то, но иначе!", а в первой строфе было "то, то, но иначе". И образ внутренних "чувствую" на протяжении всего стиха противопоставляется сенсорике и разуму. А senses - это именно сенсорика и разум, такого рода смысл, а не imaging feelings. То есть огонь можно воображать любым, но если засунуть руку, сенсорика скажет точно, какой на самом деле огонь). И вот этот смысл у Маршака да и Финкеля потерян, потому что в русском больше внутренних смыслов, нежели деления на внешние и внутренние.
Я спросил на этот счет своего сумасшедшего друга-англичанина, он говорит, что они это(переворот общепринятых пониманий у Шекспира в сонетах) называют "ирония" - jstor.org/stable/43343552 . Ну и это классика "и тело пахнет телом" - при описании "любви". "А тело пахнет так, как пахнет тело, Не как фиалки нежный лепесток." - Маршак. "Хоть благовоний много есть прекрасных, Увы, но только не в ее устах." Чайковский, а вот Финкель почти попадает в ловушку: "И в мире много ароматов есть Ее дыханья слаще и сильней;"
То есть в сонетах часто встречается двойственность и противоположность смыслов. В 1 - то что нужно давать другим себя есть, а не жить для себя одного. Тоже странно, потому что сами современные англичане-европейцы ушли от этого понимания, того что Шекспир при всей его реализованности, а не надуманности чувств, говорил против индивидуализма и мог рассуждать о долге и тп.
Но последняя строчка очень странная: Есть(в смысле поедать) в мире долг,(запятая) до гроба и(?) тебя. Как это вообще понимать?) То есть давать другим пищу твой долг, а их долг поедать всё прекрасное, что ты даешь им до гроба?
Но что интересно, если оставить то, как написано, то эти смыслы в целом остаются. Есть в мире долг до гроба, есть в мире до(у) тебя, твой долг, есть в мире твой долг до гроба. То есть поэтические фразы не отличаются однозначностью прочтения, в отличие от фраз прозы, где всё чётко и одно следует из другого.
— Я бы второе четверостишье записала бы так (по грамматике): Ни звон речей меня не утолит, Ни нежности касание не даст, Ни вкус, ни аромат не пригласит На вожделенный пир телесных яств. // Дословный перевод: И не услаждают мои уши звуки твоего языка, И нежное чувство не склонно к низменным прикосновениям, Ни вкус, ни обоняние не вызывают желания быть приглашенными На какой-либо чувственный пир наедине с тобой; // И еще я концовку не понимаю, причем ни у вас, ни у Шекспира. А у Маршака наполовину понимаю. О чем они говорят? Это как-то связано с религией?
Дословный перевод: Кто не оставляет сомнений в том, что он похож на человека, Быть рабом и вассалом твоего гордого сердца - значит быть несчастным. Пока что я считаю своим приобретением только чуму, Та, кто заставляет меня грешить, награждает меня болью.
—  "Who leaves unswayed the likeness of a man, Thy proud heart's slave and vassal wretch** to be" Кто(сердце) разрешает неуклонно быть подобным такому человеку, твоего гордого сердца(прихоти) раба и существовать подкаблучником." vassal wretch - вассал вретч, это подкаблучник, если дословно, слуга впавший в немилость и ищущий милости всеми способами.
"Only my plague thus far I count my gain, That she that makes me sin awards me pain." Только собственную хворь(недуг, бедствие, злокачественная болезнь) до сих пор я считаю моим приобретением, ту, что она, заставляющая грешить, дарит мне болью. То есть болезнь - это боль от подчинение женщине заставляющей его грешить.
В общем, я пока не знаю, дело в том, что там нетипичная конструкция, НОР стоит вначале предложения, а последние утверждение через запятую вообще без НОР или какого-то отрицания. То есть это утвердительная конструкция. Про утвердительные конструкции с НОР пока мало нашёл информации, а так же про то, когда НОР идет вначале.) Короче вот такой он, староанглийский, все не так...

Вы решили вести в рубрике "Ответы" архив своих переписок в комментариях с другими пользователями? Это не ответ. Тем более, не ваш. Не устраивайте балаган на форуме.

@Sharon отравил письмо, можно убирать почту.

Насчёт "ты" - ты это не к "себе" обращение, себя - это селф или зуселф, селф это социальный конструкт, рамка для того чтобы демонстрировать себя другим в лучшем(или худшем) свете, а ты - это настоящее "я", которое люди часто даже от себя скрывают, потому что это "голое я". И показательно, ну почему они друга придумали, потому что в современном английском нет "ты", есть только ю-"вы", а вы это слово без дефиниции я-мы-другие, просто смешанное что-то. Следующий стих сложный, попробую перевести, но там вообще все очень таинственно) И ещё у ты было отдельное окончание ST, то есть не do, а dost.

Ну я так и думала, что речь идет о настоящем  Я.  // А когда в англ. языке существовало "ты", сейчас его совсем не используют? И что значит окончание ST? // Придуманный друг мне очень помешал.  Сейчас я совершенно иначе воспринимаю Шекспира, такие чувства мне близки.

мне кажется СТ, это сокращение от есть - ist. Есть, вкушать, чувствовать, отражающее от собственную точку зрения к происходящему, а не абстрактное мнение "вы". Потому что to be - это быть,  is и формы - это являться, а не быть, то есть казаться, быть похожим на... Вообще в русском быть связано с тем, что есть, и чем можно обладать, иметь to have скорее, чем являться, другая категория, то что на что-то похоже, этим не обладаешь, а делаешь некоторое отстраненное заявление. ist - немецкое есть, созвучное с кушать, грызть essen. Ну или в русском эти два слова слились.

Исправил пока когда на если, но если мне не нравится, хотя по размеру подходит да.

При чтении стиха нарушение размера заметно сразу. Стоит перенести одно ударение, и размер уже другой. А в песенном исполнении неточности сглаживаются и кажутся допустимыми. В этом и трудность, и превосходство стихотворной речи: уложить нужное слово не просто, но в жестких рамках оно звучит по-особенному.

@Sharon ну да, в ритмическом стихе ритм может гулять более свободно, строки могут быть непропорциональны, главное чтобы слова попадали в такт. То есть я пою вот так: И пленник правит к'гда_ царь больной:  - упускаю безударную долю и добавляю паузу, что ли

У меня тут возник вопрос. Можно ли перевести сонеты, не изучая биографию Шекспира? Возник он так. Прочитав очередной раз о ренессансной дружбе, я подумала:  Как-то все идеально. А ведь люди того времени  вряд ли были такими. Были гордыми, смелыми, самоуверенными и в какой-то мере склонными к жестокости и насилию. А идеалы - они существовали, но  жизнь вносила  определенный реализм и в их творчество  тоже. Отражено ли это в сонетах.  И решила найти в Сети что-нибудь про его жизнь.

Лучше бы не смотрела, так как в жизни его полно белых пятен. Даже знаменитый портрет не точно его. А еще пообщалась с самим Шекспиром через матрицу. Он спросил, знаем ли мы, где он пропадал 7 лет, когда уехал из родного города. И еще господин Шекспир заявил, что более невежественной эпохи, чем наша, трудно представить. Вот умора, да? Так можно ли перевести сонеты, не изучая биографию Шекспира?Но вы, как я думаю, знаете очень много, может и с Шекспиром встречались)

Да сам по себе Шекспир для многих видится не исторической личностью, а мистификацией ряда ведущих писателей, вроде "Козьмы Пруткова". Потому что глубина его мыслей, языковая вариативность и прочее, это что-то экстраординарное. Я знаю очень мало, это мне кажется мне и помогает, а просто читаю слова, доверяю слову, а не своему представлению о слове. И я поправил: "И узник вылечен, но страж больной:" В оригинале "капитан больной". Но стало даже лучше, потому что это про "пленник правит" это я, честно скажу, подсмотрел у переводчиков) или где-то там, но разобравшись, понял что это ошибка.

Что же касается 10 сонета, мне кажется, вы невнимательно прочитали концовку, кто там имеется ввиду? О ком речь? Я просто сохранил слова, которые были у Шекспира, а все переводчики их изменили, и смысл изменился.

И кроме того, я даже делаю вид, или не делаю, а пытаюсь знать меньше, чем знаю, я беру "unions married" - это "брачные обеты" переводится сейчас, но переводчики даже это вымарали, потому что это давало парадокс, они там топят за "сына давай, женись" а тут,"брачные обеты-звучит плохо". Но я меняю брачные обеты, на "обеты счастья", потому что меррид - это не только женитьба, но и вообще обещание, договор, о неком счастье, получается. Разве можно "договориться о счастье"? Разве два человека или больше могут договориться чтобы оба были счастливы друг с другом? Нет, это бред. И на это указывает Ш.

Нельзя выдумать правило счастья. Но можно прийти к согласию примеряя внутренние противоречия. К согласию с самим собой прежде всего, внутри самого себя. Так что умение достигать согласия, согласия веры ли, или чего-то ещё, это и есть основа человечности, а вовсе не рацио или интеллект. Это согласие лежит в основе языка. Понимание ведущее к согласию.

Да и вообще "Ромео и Джульетта" например, это история вовсе не о любви, а о подростковой необузданной страсти, которая заканчивается нелюбовью, а смертью обоих, и не важно физической или духовной. Если читать внимательно, там постоянно указывается на это, а вовсе не на то, что любовь великая. С другой стороны, это великая страсть, природная, естественная, и она противопоставлена миру людей - политике, интригам, договорам и тп. Миру, где человек пытается играть в бога, устанавливая законы, вступающие в противоречие с натурой человека, плодя уродство, а не красоту. Красота и природа синонимы у Ш

И в этом он маг, алхимик, а не религиозный деятель или учёный-врач-доктор. 16 век это слом сознания людей с мышлением мифическо-магическим, на рациональное. Слом мира. Магия уходит из мира, появляются вещи. Душа мира увядает, появляется расчет, вероятности, статистика и прочее. Время, которое было цикличным, становится осевым, линейным, начинает течь вперёд, от прошлого в будущее, минуя настоящее.

Да, и вот ещё, дело в том, что у Ш огромное количество местоимений, которое игнорируется переводчиками. То есть на самом деле, его стихи, это взаимодействие этих местоимений, спор между ними. А вот специфические термины, довольно редки, из терминов я встретил пока только АУДИТ, больше не приходит в голову. Все остальные слова аутентичны, и вот вы приводите стихи Пушкина, у Пушкина в этом плане стилистика более смешанная, чем у Ш., в том стихе, более терминологичная "дворовый", ещё что-то.. - это же термины, а не слова натурального языка.

Сонеты » Сонет 131
Перевод Самуила Яковлевича Маршака
 Ты прихоти полна и любишь власть,
 Подобно всем красавицам надменным.
 Ты знаешь, что моя слепая страсть
 Тебя считает даром драгоценным.

 Пусть говорят, что смуглый облик твой
 Не стоит слез любовного томленья, -
 Я не решаюсь в спор вступать с молвой,
 Но спорю с ней в своем воображенье.

 Чтобы себя уверить до конца
 И доказать нелепость этих басен,
 Клянусь до слез, что темный цвет лица
 И черный цвет волос твоих прекрасен.

 Беда не в том, что ты лицом смугла, -
 Не ты черна, черны твои дела!

Рецензия на перевод Маршака
Все очень красивенько, в духе русской классики. Запоминается  сразу, смысл понятен: надменная красавица мучает своих  поклонников, а  они в ответ считают, что она смугла и некрасива.  Да, она смугла, но не в этом дело. Она нехорошо поступает —  вот что огорчает. (Не ты черна, черны твои дела!)
Недостаток перевода в слишком вольной трактовке лексического наполнения текста, так что похоже на пересказ, а не перевод.
Рецензия на другой перевод.
Достоинство — близость к оригинальному тексту. В целом перевод мне ОЧЕНЬ НРАВИТСЯ.  Отмечу еще, что ритм стиха выдержан более четко, чем у Маршака.
Но концовку я совсем не понимаю: надо ли осуждать красавицу, в чем ее оболгали?  Какова истинная мораль?
Для себя я форму немного поправила — чтобы красиво читалось (очень надеюсь, что автор меня простит). Хотелось бы еще рифму в конце  изменить, чтобы кончалась на ударный гласный (так выразительнее). Получился такой вариант:
 Ты верно от тирана создана,
 Содеяна надменной и пустой,
 И это сердца глупого вина,
 Что мнит тебя редчайшей красотой.

 Однако, это те, что за глаза
 Твердящие — на них ты не гляди,
 Пусть врут  они  —  я не рискну сказать,
 За что себя кляну, когда один.

 Но в том уверен, снова поклянусь,
 Что раз клонится низко голова
 Не смеющих в лицо твоё взглянуть, —
 Твой  чёрен цвет, но чернота права.

 Что не несешь черна в свои дела  —
 За это и оболгана была.

Сонет 127
 Прекрасным не считался черный цвет,
 Когда на свете красоту ценили.
 Но, видно, изменился белый свет, -
 Прекрасное подделкой очернили...

Сонет 127 это нечто, просто абракадабра какая-то, таинственное заклинание.
Я сейчас сравниваю 4 редакции: оригинал, дословный перевод, перевод Маршака и ваш.
Читаю  дословный перевод, весьма туманный, и пытаюсь понять эту историю. Получается (очень примерно) так.
Раньше темное считалось некрасивым, но вот появилась красота, далекая от природы, порожденная фальшивым искусством. Прекрасное очернили, истинная красота  стала незаконной.  У милой красоты нет имени, нет священной обители. Она осквернена и живёт в бесчестии. Но Природа красива сама по себе, даже если считается некрасивой. Но все твердят, что красиво именно искусственное. Поэтому черные глаза моей милой кажутся  скорбящими и оттого прекрасными.  Чернота стала красотой.
Сравниваю с Маршаком – слегка похоже. Сравниваю с вашим переводом – почти ничего общего. Смотрю в Сети первый попавшийся разбор – там такой бред написан (про цвет волос).  https://proza.ru/2015/07/20/645
Чтобы отвлечься от черно-светлой философии, предлагаю посмотреть сонет 144. Там все любопытненько.
 На радость и печаль, по воле рока,
 Два друга, две любви владеют мной:
 Мужчина светлокудрый, светлоокий
 И женщина, в чьих взорах мрак ночной.

А это комментарий: Далее мы узнаем, что друг и возлюбленная поэта сблизились и оба, таким образом, изменили ему. Но это не убило в нем ни привязанности к другу, ни страсти к возлюбленной. https://studfile.net/preview/8673312/page:12/
Похоже на правду?
О сонете 128
 Едва лишь ты, о музыка моя,
 Займешься музыкой, встревожив строй
 Ладов и струн искусною игрой,
 Ревнивой завистью терзаюсь я.

Утро началось с вопроса — он мне так ничего и не написал?..  А потом утонула в музыке и стихах. Днем не будет времени, а вечером к ним вернусь. Я догадалась — вы и есть Шекспир, да...
Средневековье, театр… Чувства переносят в другое время, иначе невозможно сонеты ни понять, ни перевести. Но чувства нерациональны, заставляют страдать, так зачем они  нам? Все-таки нужен другой перевод, не рассудочный, а наполненный истинной страстью.
А еще вчерашний пейзаж вдохновляет для смещения сознания)
Под окном кочевники поставили белые шатры, жарко. Пахнет травой и лошадьми. Кочевники тоже настоящие — полотняные одежды, устали от рыцарских боев, обливаются водой. Танцы на городской площади, духовая музыка:  как грациозны и зажигательны россияночки в русских одеждах, а танцы просты и все же необычны. Публика тоже увлечена, прыгают дети. Все это называется фестиваль «Времена и годы».
О ЗАДАЧАХ ПРИ ПЕРЕВОДЕ СОНЕТОВ
Я хочу пока остановиться на задачах, которые надо решить при переводе  (сонет 128 пока не разбирала). Это (1) точное соответствие значению слов и (2) правильное понимание грамматики.  Здесь важно не ошибиться, иначе  стих будет неправильно понят. Это то, что можно назвать его реконструкцией.  А сам художественный перевод только основан на этом материале, но это уже поэзия со своими особыми требованиями (кисть художника, оживляющая материю).
Важен ли здесь анализ стихотворной формы? Разумеется,  при реконструкции мы воссоздаем форму стиха. По общему мнению, сонет написан пятистопным ямбом,  но возможно ли иное понимание структуры?  Я могу предположить, что сонет может иметь более сложную  «музыкальную»  структуру (ритмический рисунок),  но при этом стихотворный размер сохраняется.
Рассмотрим, к примеру,  структуру песенного текста, в котором используется пятистопный ямб (стихи Н. Рубцова).  Мы видим разное деление строк на две части, но это именно пятистопный ямб.
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/16130954813262573857
 Я буду дОлго  / гнать велосипЕд.
 В глухих лугАх /   его остановлЮ.
 Нарву цветОв  / и подарю букЕт
 Той дЕвушке,  / которую люблЮ.

(Любопытная цитата:  «Стиховая стопа не могла возникнуть из музыкального такта, потому что европейская музыка до XVII в. не знала тактов».  Изменилась музыкальная форма?)
Как размер учитывается при переводе? Думаю, что пятистопный ямб нужно сохранить в любом  случае,  но в тоже время  обратить особое внимание на слова,  попадающие  в сильную позицию по тоническому ударению (это повышение или понижение тона на ударном слоге фразовых отрезков в строке).
О размере сонета 129
По моим заимствованным сведениям от ямба отличаются три сонета – 99, 126, 145.  Сонет 129 – тоже пятистопный ямб.
Двусложный размер, как мне кажется,  определяется на слух: там больше ударных гласных, он как бы разделен на более мелкие отрезки, в нем больше движения. А в трехсложном размере ударных гласных меньше, он более плавный.
Если брать длинные русские слова и укладывать их в двусложный ямб, то появляются безударные стопы, то есть ритмика меняется. Кроме того, учитываются мужские и женские рифмы.
Я читаю так:
  ИздЕрж/ки дУ/ха и/стыдА/ растрА/та -
  Вот сла/дострА/стье /в дЕйст/вии/ ОнО
  БезжА/лостно,/ ковАр/но, бесновАто,
  ЖестО/ко, грУ/бо, Я/рости /полнО.

Из статьи ЗАМЕТКИ К ПЕРЕВОДАМ ШЕКСПИРОВСКИХ СОНЕТОВ – 2,  вот с какими людьми вам было бы интересно поговорить)
Таким образом, принцип неожиданности в концовке сонета выдержан во всех 154 стихотворениях; из этого следует, что «эффект неожиданности» был для Шекспира важен и что, по мере их написания, сонеты предназначались для чтения вслух в кругу общения, ограниченном друзьями Шекспира: только в этом случае каждый сонет требовал такого строгого подхода, поскольку шутки сонетных замков были рассчитаны именно на неожиданность, а лирическая направленность – на усиление подчеркнутой сентенцией;
Да-да-да, мне почти нравится)) Но кое-что не укладывается в размер:
 О смерти лишь прошу, опустошён,
 Как странник вечный средь безлюдных мест,
 И цель забыл свою, ИЗОБРАЖЕН
 Шутом и  потерял доверья вес.

 И девой нежной предан грубо был,
 И славы злато мутно от стыда,
 И важный кто-то мой роток прикрыл???  Не очень...
 И скверна, верно, вся моя еда,

 И правда, если прав любой дурак,
 И истина зовётся ПРОСТОТОЙ,
 И если сильный избегает драк,
 И пленник правит, ЕСЛИ царь больной,– 

Опустошён, я прочь сбегу – молю,
Храни, по гроб, ОДНУ любовь мою.

О СОНЕТЕ 90, размер, ритмика
Уж Ес/ли ты/ разлЮ/ бишь — так /тепЕрь/, 3 удар.
ТепЕрь, когда / весь мИр/ со мной/ в раздОре. 3 уд. 
Будь сА/мой горь/кой из / моих/ потЕрь, 2 уд. 
Но тОль/ко не /послЕд/ней кап/лей гО/ря! 3 уд.

Пятистопный ямб везде соблюдается строго, отклонения при обычном прочтении стиха сразу определяются на слух.
О ритмике. Из музыкальной грамоты. Ритм образуется при чередовании звуков разной длительности, ритмический рисунок может совпадать с размером,  но часто отличается.  Это мы видим по количеству  ударных позиций  в каждой строке, где делается тоническое ударение (повышение или понижении тона, изменение длительности).
Русская речь музыкальна по своей природе, в ней обозначен ритм. Беречь ее надо  и хранить, а то и потерять недолго.
Если вспомнить про интонационный анализ, то здесь все на месте: фраза делится на отдельные синтагмы/части, обозначенные тоническим тактовым ударением. По смыслу они соответствуют словосочетаниям или отдельным группам слов. Внутри синтагмы ударением выделено значимое слово.
Я думаю, что в современном английском языке этого нет, но, возможно,  было раньше. Это к вашему высказыванию: «У Шекспира же, английский больше похож на русский английский…»
Кстати есть сервисная программа, определяющая размер конкретного стиха, например: https://rifmoved.ru/sergei_aleksandrovich_esenin_sobake_kachalova
При начальном переводе отдельные детали не так важны — на первом плане удачное создание художественного образа. Здесь рядом с поэтом муза и вдохновение — есть! нашел!
А доработка деталей, знаки — это все потом. Иногда одна фраза многого стоит —  ведь они не равнозначны. Есть приглушенный фон, а есть центр притяжения, который   в наибольшей степени соответствует содержанию стиха. Ну это я так думаю)
Я пока про сонет 66, еще раз послушала. До совершенства совсем немного.  Союз «когда» надо бы заменить «если», по семантике они взаимозаменяемы. Но если оставить «когда», то получается неправильный ямб, что определяется на слух:
И плЕн/ ник прА/вит, Ес/ли цАрь / больнОй…
// Ах, какой у вас приятный голос, какое исполнение!  Просто театральный талант, Никитин отдыхает. (Послушала разные муз. записи сонета, ничего не нравится.) // Вы еще не готовы к дебюту с этим сонетом (текст + песня) на Прозе.ру (к примеру).  Будете иметь успех, или я ничего не понимаю в стихах))
Про сонет 2. Тоже все классно, интересная трактовка темы, интересное исполнение. А что не так?
Сама тема не очень выигрышная и занимательная для читателя. Грустно, что красота увянет, ну да что об этом думать. А сильные эмоции в другом — в ПРОТИВОРЕЧИЯХ текущей жизни. Особый смысл стиха тоже не поймут. Ну это я так думаю)  Поэтому для первых переводов лучше на соблюдать ХРОНОЛОГИЮ, а выбрать что-нибудь яркое и актуальное. // Зачем он вообще поучал своего юного друга?  Ему 28 — 35 лет, сам еще молодой. В современном обществе такую ренессансную дружбу не поймут, хотя в русской истории были примеры.
Сонет 3 (звуковой файл) Как красиво, как талантливо! Я уже слушаю только голос, не особо вникая в содержание. Не знаю, понравится ли вам такая оценка)

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Это верно.  Ценятся только оригинальные произведения, а всяких "исследований" по Шекспиру  видимо-невидимо.  Берегите вдохновение)

Ну и я ещё не беру внутренних рифм, такие тоже бывают. Когда в строках слова укладывающиеся в ритм в середине имеют рифмованное звучание. Хотя нужно хотя бы ритмики добиться. Ну и я почитал уже википедию по 128, про blessed wood - рояль "в кустах".) Мне хватило подобного бреда) Просто меня мысли посторонние часто раздражают, особенно если глупости) Словарь этимологический помог, потому там blessed от краплёный кровью, древние значение было. Хотя я и без этого вроде не заблудился трех соснах.

Ну и я так понимаю, что у англичан с этим проблемы, русские слова сложно перепутать, а в английском куда больше омонимии, в том числе и частей речи. У нас стих где три раза будет написано "деревянное" сложно придумать) У Шекспира же, английский больше похож на русский английский, у него слова не всегда на тех местах, на котором они должны быть в современно английском, гораздо свободнее, артикли не всегда, предлоги не всегда, как мне кажется) получается что нам даже понятнее, чем сегодняшним англичанам)

"я прочь сбегу – молю" - не хочу тире) у Шекспира только запятые, ну ещё точки с запятой и двоеточия) Мне это ближе, вообще я не долюбливаю тирешечку. Стрижён - наверное не совсем корректно, но это не только про стрижку, это вроде как "постриг", то есть прослыл шутом). Но я подумаю насчёт может быть иной формы)

То есть вот пример ритмической фразы: "О смерти лишь прошу, опустошён:" - 6\4, она не бьется на 5\5, 5\5 - это когда одно утверждение и ему противопоставленное - "в глухих лугах\его остановлю" - каждая часть самодостаточна, и это вполне думаю касается вашего ритмического анализа. А вот у Шекспира - "Tired with all these,\ for restful death I cry:" - 4\6. Можно перевернуть: опустошён, о смерти я молю, - но это будет уже другая фраз по ритмике, и на музыку, вероятно, её можно переложить, но придётся менять акцент, а вот 5-5 на ту же музыкальную ритмику переложить сложнее и не факт, получится ли

Сделав\ мёртвый\ пень красней\ губ живых. - Making\ dead wood\ more blest than\ living lips. - "++ |++ |++" очень ритмичная фраза, танцевальная, такая, что прямо хоть в пляс. Совсем не рассудочное 5\5 - аргумент-контраргумент.

Или вот: Yet so they mourn,\ becoming of their woe,(4\6)
That every tongue says\ beauty should look so.)(5\5).  Вот что у Маршака: Но так идет им\ черная фата,(5\5)
Что красотою\ стала чернота!(5\5) Вот Фикель: Они прекрасны.\ И твердят уста,(4\6)
Что черною\ должна быть\ красота.(4\6) А вот Чайковский: И эта грусть\ так чудно ей к лицу,
Что каждый в нем\ признает красоту.(4\6)(4\6) - У меня вариант с повтором (4\6, 4\6, 4\6, 5\5) 5\5 - это два равнозначных по мелодике(силе) утверждения: Ведь в чёрном мире,\ некрасивых нет.

То есть у Маршака сонеты максимально нединамичные, хотя, 90 отличается "Уж если ты\ разлюбишь\ так теперь"(4\3\3) Поэтому он самый мелодичный и песенный. Ну и у него выход часто за десятку, потому что "Теперь когда\ весь мир со мной в раз до ре"(4\7), но я не знаю, насколько он или другие вообще это просчитывали, а это именно что просчитывается.

Исправил на "шутом ряжён", НРКЯ: "Пуще отца родного возрадовался Алексей знакомому мужичку, что великим постом ряжён был Патапом Максимычем по последнему пути свезти остаток горянщины на Городецкую пристань.")))) Победа) Спасибо, стрижён правда было слишком сложно для восприятия.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/MlXnokunlm_Vdw - 2 (призОм не хочу править, считаю, тут именно на 2 слог, потому что это не вещь-приз.) https://disk.yandex.ru/d/PtSNDI78wdJqNw - 66 исправленный вариант.

"любовь одну мою" - не хочу менять порядок, специально так сделал.) Ну и во втором, как видите, смысл вышел иной, ребёнок не твой, а ребёнок в тебе, тот ты, которого ты вырастил. Это про психологию, и про принятие себя-тебя) "And see thy blood warm when thou feel'st it cold." - и(уметь) видеть теплоту(в) крови, когда чувствуешь близость старость. "How much more praise deserved thy beauty's use,
If thou couldst answer" - то есть ты сможешь получить приз теплоты, если можешь сможешь себя принять в эти моменты. Нет там никакого ребёнка другого и женщины черной) это все про внутренние моменты.

Про внутренний мир, а не про внешний. В противном случае это было бы типичным назиданием, но как видите, Шекспир уходит от стандартных нравоучений. "This were to be new made when thou art old," - это понимание будет твоим новым бытием(ту би), когда проникнешься искусством старости. Ребёнок вряд ли был бы нью мейд) для человека, который вдруг впал в кризис среднего возраста. То есть в том стихе рояль в кустах, а в этом ребёнок из кустов) Не было и вдруг он осознал, что у него оказывается ребёнок есть! Нате! НУ и ещё "согреть кровь" это призыв выпить, типа тост, следующий сонет начинает с glass

Я там написала кое-чего, посмотрите...

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/wqRzBNONZ037Sw - 3 ещё раз, стихи тоже слушайте, все вместе нужно воспринимать) вы мне нужны, не тоните. Нет про друга это, нет никакого друга, нет никакого ребёнка, нет никакой женщины, ну или они есть, но стихи не про них и не для них конкретно, они шире и это про внутренний диалог. Можете сравнить переводы третьего, они неверно интерпретировали 2, и далее пошли сохраняя ошибку к третьему, сужая проблематику до рождения "наследника", а это не про рождение потомства, а вообще про творчество. Быть или не быть. Женщина - это анима.

Возможно... А зачем вы так красиво поете?  Магия звука - и больше ничего. Хорошо, я постараюсь понять ваши мысли и что нет друга. А разве по переводам Маршака это можно понять? Кто это вообще понимает?

Почему есть смысл переводить по порядку, потому что идет развитие образа, сначала это завязь и цветок, потом цветок становится сорняком и пустоцветом, а завязь превращается в мать, которая не может родить, так как лишина позабыта, либо стала сущностью себялюбия и живёт только ради страстей. А у человека появляется двойник-другой, на которого он смотрит и не может принять, осознать, что это он сам.

Не знаю, по переводам Маршака мало что можно понять, мне кажется) без обид) Хотя 90 сонет очень даже неплох.

Сонет 90?  А разве это не о любви к женщине или еще кому? Неужели тоже аллегория?

Ладно похвалю себя немного) вот это это весьма поэтично вышло:
"Но через эти стёкла по часам
Уходит время золотом морщин." Ещё то куда сажают семена, чело, лоб оно же поле, на котором появляются борозды-морщины. И все это еще связано со временем. То есть во втором он пишет "борозды и вспаханное поле", а в этом он пишет морщины, и тут же вспоминается 2, и становится понятно о чём речь, или нет?) Поэтому я это все сюда добавил и смешал, получились такие строчки.

Нет,  Я все-таки вам плохой друг и советчик. Может, вы и правы, но мне нужны живые эмоции. Я вообще не люблю символизм, мысли надо писать не стихами, а прозой. Мысли должны рождаться чувствами, и первое восприятие поэзии - это именно чувства.

Ну вот вам прозаическая добавка) Мысли или есть, или их нет, Логические рассуждения - это совсем не всегда мысли, даже наоборот, мысль связана с образом мышления. И это не символизм, я бы не сказал, что это символизм, тут все в целом и так понятно, нет символизма. Образность есть, символизма нет. Символизм привязан к вещам, это про быт, а не бытие. А образы бытия они типа универсальны.

Да без разницы, как назвать. я не хочу думать в тот момент, когда читаю стихи. Вы, наверное, не рассчитывали на такого читателя)

Меня просто в юности научили думать, о чём стихи, так и пошло.) Точнее даже о чём песня. Я просто иногда забываю, что вещи для меня очевидные, могут быть не очевидными для других. Короче, можно и даже нужно, наверное, думать, о чем песня или стих, иначе зачем вообще это?) Ну то есть можно быть потребителем, мне хочется понять как стих сочинён, что ли.

Я не знаю, что с вам делать). Вы сами себя не понимаете, Откуда тогда столько чувства в вашем исполнении? Эмоции там просто зашкаливают, а вы мне рассказываете про схемы.

Не понимаю себя?) Ну может не всегда, но вообще, я пытаюсь понять в том числе себя) "Вы, наверное, не рассчитывали на такого читателя) " - я ни на кого не рассчитывал, но я рад, что вы если и не читатель, то благодарный слушатель.

Комическая ситуация, да?) Просто в духе Шекспира) Слушатель, который слышит только голос и отдельные слова...

Вообще, если честно) я когда пишу песню, я каждый раз рыдаю от переизбытка чувств, потом становится полегче) но это показатель того, что песня трогает за душу)

Вот так!  А от меня хотите,  чтобы  я рассуждала про ваши схемы?  У меня вообще восприятие мира чисто эмоциональное,  я только делаю вид, что разбираюсь в логике)  Да вы сами себя послушайте...  Вы там совсем другой, будто и не вы.  Какая-то странная история, мне уже давно кажется,  что в вас есть что-то необычное.  А вам так не кажется?

Ну это просто внутреннее) Это нормально, хуже когда этого нет) Я там ещё поправил "А он лежит в гробу себя любя", эгоизм не относится к душе, вообще там сложно конечно, это как полкурса философии - Эго, Я-другой, другие, душа, Ты и тп.) Так что ничего страшного, если сразу не все понятно) Я вообще типа пишу книгу по философии, но лучше, если это будут стихи, а ещё лучше с музыкой, так что меня сейчас все устраивает. И даже не страшно, если и потом не понтяно) всего не нужно знать, если чувствуете.

В общем непростые стихи, не все так банально, как кажется, но это не значит, что нельзя их понять. Ну и в общем Шекспир пока оправдывает мои ожидания вполне, можно понимать мир через Шекспира.. И что мне ещё нравится, что у него есть "Ты" которого нет в современном английском

Хотя не так, это нормально, если это есть, а не задавлено, но вообще, это есть не у всех людей, по моим ощущениям, может так, а может задавлено в зародыше. Не знаю почему. Посмотрите фильм "Я и другие" СССР, смотрели?

Нет, но уже догадываюсь о чем это. Ваше "ты"– это видение и понимание себя? Но это у кого что... Вижу себя со стороны, да. // Если вам нужны схемы, то пусть так и будет. А я хочу слушать вас... И я хотела бы, чтобы вы  продолжили заниматься переводами.

Чтобы утешить себя, пытаюсь рассмешить.  Вспомнилась ситуация:  "Трудно сказать, что именно подвело Ивана Николаевича – изобразительная ли сила его таланта или полное незнакомство с вопросом, по которому он писал, – но Иисус у него получился, ну, совершенно живой, некогда существовавший Иисус, только, правда, снабженный всеми отрицательными чертами Иисуса. Берлиоз же хотел доказать поэту, что главное не в том, каков был Иисус, плох ли, хорош ли, а в том, что Иисуса-то этого, как личности, вовсе не существовало на свете...

)) я несколько иначе отношусь к мифам). Я бы хотел, чтобы вы посмотрели), он не настолько сложный, не так как это звучит, просто популярный-научный фильм рассчитанный на широкую аудиторию. Не знаю почему, я этот фильм советую многим людям, и так никто и не посмотрел, как мне кажется, в итоге не то, что я не могу обсуждать какие-то популярные вещи, но когда речь заходит о чем-то важном для меня, оказывается, что прям не с кем обсудить, чувствую себя Кассандрой, знаете миф про Кассандру?

А что вы хотели?  Кассандра получила дар от богов и не расплатилась за него, где это видано!  Плохо. когда  боги  гневаются, имейте  в виду) // А я. пожалуй,  очень увлеклась Шекспиром, надо немного отдохнуть. Спасибо вам за творчество, и я постараюсь посмотреть фильм. Ну и еще несколько слов про Шекспира.

Людям нужны не идеи, а чувства.  Иначе они мало что понимают, и научить их ничему невозможно.  Современникам сонеты казались «сладкими как сахар»,   но очень скоро их считают «педантическим и скучным вздором».  Да,  они совершенны по форме и это не отдельные стихи, а нечто цельное.   Да что с того,  уж очень они рассудочные  и условные.  Это уже тогда так  казалось! А наш мир и вовсе иной. Какие там циклы — мы всё воспринимаем в виде фрагментов. Чтобы привлечь внимание читателя, сначала нужна картинка из нескольких красочных пятен.  Тогда они подойдут, чтобы лучше посмотреть.

Тут нужно знать, с какой целью делается перевод:  (1) Лично для себя, чтобы понять Шекспира.  (2) Для языковедов, чтобы предложить научному обществу правильный перевод,  максимально приближенный к оригиналу.  (2) Для широкой аудитории, чтобы  сонеты соответствовали  духовным потребностям современного общества, но были при этом истинным переводом Шекспира, а не свободным пересказом (как у Маршака).

"Людям нужны не идеи, а чувства" - есть(поедать) мира долг? Мне вот интересно, что я пока не встретил ни разу упоминания бога, хотя есть Природа, лоно Природы, телесность, воплощенность, мне кажется стихи актуальны, потому что сегодня Природа опять популярнее бога, ощущение, что живём в средневековье) такие вот вижу циклы.

"А я. пожалуй, очень увлеклась Шекспиром, надо немного отдохнуть." Думаю, отдыхать можно, благо Шекспир никуда сбежит)

Это кому что можно, каждому своё.  Мы в мелочах  свободны в своем выборе, а по большому счету все в мире происходит по воле богов, и человек здесь не исключение.  Такая точка зрения какому циклу соответствует? Средневековье ко времени Шекспира как раз только-только кончилось. Началось как бы второе Возрождение.  Кстати, о чувствах. Их становится все меньше, и по качеству они уже не такие. Говорят, в будущем их будут во флакончиках продавать.  Вас хорошо оценят))

А у вас разве нет записи 4-го сонета? А других? Очень хотелось бы послушать, пжста. Или пришлите мне на почту, а?  Я вам тогда ее оставлю.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/VE0CKhOxcFMmEg -4, https://disk.yandex.ru/d/hbkfEVSt_ufvCQ -5. Других каких? Если хотите, присылайте почту)

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/JDjVdFeKGM0afQ - 3 исправленный.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/2lI4YFpmpryTvw -короче 7) я старался, но такие партии петь фальцетом дело непростое), так чтобы звучало серьёзно и академично) надеюсь, когда-нибудь будет лучшая версия исполнения.

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YlvjYcle21FUcg - 9
