Сонеты Шекспира в переводе Маршака: в чем своеобразие художественных средств выразительности?
 «Это была эпидемия, повальное читательское 
 заболевание, — вспоминал известный переводчик 
 Игнатий Ивановский. — Сонеты читали с эстрады, 
 переписывали друг у друга, днем держали на рабочем 
 столе, а ночью под подушкой».


Изданные в 1948 году сонеты Маршака имели оглушительный успех, но потом восторги приутихли. Появилась такая точка зрения: «При всей огромной талантливости Маршака его переводы не передают в полной мере своеобразия лирики Шекспира», а спокойный и уравновешенный автор  отличается «от неистового, блистательного и страстного поэта английских сонетов».

Появилось множество новых переводов, но…  всем им чего-то не хватало. А вот чего? Говорят, что каноничности, законченности, классического совершенства.

Но это все общие слова. Так в чем же "магия" Маршака,  почему литературоведы до сих пор считают его переводы образцовыми? КАКИЕ-ТО ОСОБЫЕ СРЕДСТВА ВЫРАЗИТЕЛЬНОСТИ ИЛИ ЧТО? Если знать эту «тайну», то можно предложить перевод не хуже, а то и лучше канонического. Как-никак почти 100 лет прошло, что-то да и изменилось.


Это и есть ОЧЕНЬ КОНКРЕТНЫЙ ВОПРОС к участникам форума. Интересна ваша точка зрения как читателей, лингвистов и любителей изящной словесности.
Могу еще КОНКРЕТНЕЕ: Каковы достоинства и недостатки переводов Маршака? Как сохранить одно и уйти от другого? Или нужно нечто совсем новое, чтобы поразить русского читателя?
P. S. Когда погружаешься в атмосферу Шекспира и понимаешь эту сверхзадачу, то невольно возникает мысль: а что если попробовать перевести сонет? Ну хотя бы не весь, а одно четверостишье... Может быть, так можно попасть в творческую мастерскую Маршака.
Не стоит забывать, что поэт изучал тот исторический период (первая публикация всех сонетов 1609 год). Новое время, 1-й период с начала 16 века. Разрушение старого уклада жизни, развитие науки и техники, уменьшение влияния церкви.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
В вопросе использованы материалы этой статьи.
Краткий пересказ статьи: ЛАБИРИНТ, 7 июн 2018
В. Шекспир: Сонеты
Как менялось восприятие Шекспира русскими читателями
Еще в начале XX века о сонетах весьма пренебрежительно отзывались даже профессионалы. С. А. Венгеров, подготовивший знаменитое собрание сочинений Шекспира, говорил, что шекспировские сонеты — «рассудочно-отточенные и условные» стихи, в которых отсутствует лирическая страстность, — написаны в «холодных, придворно-галантных формах». Примерно тогда же А. Л. Соколовский, удостоенный за переводы Шекспира Пушкинской премии Академии наук, утверждал, что сонетная форма — не более чем «стихотворный хлам». Невозможно было представить тогда, какой невероятный восторг переживет через несколько десятилетий читающая Россия, открыв для себя «Сонеты» Шекспира в переводах Самуила Яковлевича Маршака (1887–1964).
Маршак не был первым русским переводчиком «Сонетов». Художественную почву, на которой состоялось его открытие, во многом подготовили предшественники. … Но звездным часом стали и продолжают оставаться переводы Маршака, хотя судьба его переводческого открытия оказалась непростой. Поначалу слава Маршака была просто оглушительной. Невозможно переоценить восторг, с каким его приняли читатели и литературные критики…
Однако начиная с 1960-х годов ситуация изменилась. Потрясением для читающей России стала напечатанная в 1969 году статья М. Л. Гаспарова и Н. С. Автономовой «Сонеты Шекспира — переводы Маршака», где прозвучало серьезное сомнение в точности переводов Маршака. «Спокойный, величественный, уравновешенный и мудрый поэт русских переводов, — уверяли авторы, — отличается от неистового, неистощимого, блистательного и страстного поэта английских сонетов…» Позднее об этом же скажет выдающийся отечественный шекспировед А. А. Аникст: «При всей огромной талантливости Маршака, его переводы не передают в полной мере своеобразия лирики Шекспира».
Возникшая ситуация инициировала невероятную множественность новых переводов. Стало понятно, что канонизированных переводов в принципе не может быть и каждое новое время открывает новое в переводимых шедеврах…
Тем не менее время показало: переводческая слава Маршака не меркнет и никогда не померкнет…  Этот перевод был сделан не просто с языка на язык — Маршак переводил из литературы в литературу, изумительно воссоздав великолепие и изысканное благородство принимающей классической русской словесности. Комментируя в 2001 году переиздание своей статьи, Гаспаров сказал, что переводов, притязающих сменить Маршака, появилось очень много, но ни в одном из них нет такой законченности нового поэтического стиля, какой была у Маршака законченность старого классического стиля…
Тема также обсуждается  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480813/О-сонетах-Шекспира-в-переводе-Маршака-Опыт-новых-переводов

То что я читаю, у Маршака переводы не соответствуют во многом написанному в оригинале, хотя местами очень поэтичны, но это другие стихи. А из трех переводов которые даны в сравнении, наиболее точны и близки к оригиналу переводы Финкеля. То есть Маршак писал какие-то свои стихи, но эти стихи нельзя назвать плохими, отличные стихи.

Другие стихи, да.  Но почему они читаются образцовым переводом сонетов Шекспира.  Так никто лучше и не написал, а ведь как старались. Так в чем здесь тайна, вы можете сказать? Или фишка, на современном языке?

Не знаю почему, просто Маршак эталонный советский переводчик, прежде всего детской литературы, а Финкель почему-то нет, так сложилось. Но Маршак он ну прямо много всего переводил, он очень плодовитый, так что сталинка была, конечно, заслуженной. Почему-то имена одних мы знаем, а имена других не менее значимых личностей не особо.

Работу найти не могу в интернете, даже в продаже, вообще нет. Но видимо что-то ну очень политическое и актуальное... Видимо не в том полит лагере оказался, а Маршак, он менее политизированный, если что, придумает что-то своё красивое... Поэтому для массового читателя Маршак более нейтральный, то есть классический. Может так.

Публика открыла в Маршаке нечто необыкновенное. Я недавно прочитала сонет 141, причем совершенно случайно, но он поразил меня  с первой строки. В нем метафоры совершенно особенные, так можно писать в состоянии сдвинутого сознания, особой погруженности. В 16 веке люди мыслили иначе, но Маршак даже не старается этого передать.  Он переносит своего героя в наше время, но при это использует особенную поэтику.  Его упрекают в отсутствии чувственности, и ее действительно у него нет. Но на этих чувствах он строит особую духовность.

Именно так я поняла сонет, а сейчас вижу, что у Шекспира  совсем  не духовная страстность, а очень даже плотская.

В этом и успех Маршака: он решил ничего не адаптировать, а написать новые стихи, взяв за основу работы Шекспира

Допустим, но почему-то в этих его стихах Шекспира оказалось больше, чем во всех других переводах, которые были близки к оригинальному тексту. Почему же так?

Не знаю, почему, он же поменял оригинал очень сильно, в итоге идея не передаётся. Даже по тому отрезку, что я переводил: "Ее глаза на звезды не похожи
Нельзя уста кораллами назвать,
Не белоснежна плеч открытых кожа,
И черной проволокой вьется прядь"
В первой строчке совершенно убрана резкость (her eyes NOTHING like sun), в третьей строчке поменял грубое breasts и dun на белоснежную кожу... совершенно неправильное восприятие получается, также количество слогов не то...

Переводы Маршака, конечно, не идеальны, но в них много образности, поэтичности. Да и в любом переводе неизбежны потери. Некоторые места в переводе Маршака мне даже нравятся больше, чем в оригинале.

Переводы Маршака, вероятно, надо считать особой поэзией со своей задачей,темами, худ. образами и т.д.  В этом плане  творчество Маршака достойно восхищения и самых высоких оценок.  Но некоторые его сонеты весьма далеки от оригинала, хотя это совсем не упрек.  К примеру, сравните  сонет 66 в переводе и в оригинале.  Он просто иначе понял тему, и  мне очень нравится  его перевод. Но в изображении Шекспира оригинальный  стих тоже  красочен и хорош и может волновать не меньше, в том числе наших современников.

И вот еще спрошу: в сонете 130 с каким ударением читается "проволокой", чтобы уложиться в размер?

Глаза моей любви – не Солнца вовсе;
Коралл – алее цвета её губ;
Снег белый если, что ж тогда её грудь просит;
И чёрный локон так на нежность скуп.
Пытался быть ближе к тексту оригинала – не вышло, хотя, мне кажется, есть моменты довольно точные (ну, не мне судить). Постоянно сравнивая пять переводов (Маршака, Чайковского, Финкеля, уважаемых Sharon и Арчи), очень трудно найти своё, хотелось не повторяться.
P. S. Первоначально рассчитывал перевести весь сонет. На второй строчке я понял, что не сразу :)) До следующих вдохновений!

До самой отправки начало было такое: "Любимые глаза...", всё время хочется что-то переделать, видишь изъяны и даже грамматические неточности...

Любимые глаза слишком современно, глаза моей любви необычнее и лучше,  как раз под средневековье.))  // Спасибо!!   Мне все очень нравится, кроме третьей строки. (Две первые очень близки к оригиналу.)  А почему вы ушли из размера?  Наверное, это не по правилам)) Дословно:  «Если снег белый, то ее грудь  надо назвать коричневой». Но уложить это  в размер одной строки архитрудно.  Здесь приходится использовать метафору. Но насколько метафоричен был староанглийский язык, трудно сказать. // Кстати,  когда у вас по расписанию следующее вдохновение?  Для конкурса, например))

@Sharon Конечно, я знаю, что третья строка на два слога больше, но именно на два (не на один), что, думаю допустимо. Тем более что у самого Шекспира, по моему, четвёртая строка "страдает" этим же, не находите? // Вдохновение по расписанию не вызовешь.

@Sharon А, и ещё. Мне нужно было повторить местоимение "её". Без него, во-первых, грубо звучит "грудь", а во-вторых, можно подумать о своей груди (сердце...).

У господина Шекспира  стихи довольно условные в этом плане.  Я тут прочитала, что в Италии его поэтом вообще не считают: "Разве он писал стихи?" // Маршак очень деликатно называл предмет в ед. числе:  А грудь ее белым- бела, Как будто, ранняя зима Своим дыханьем намела Два этих маленьких холма. // Но в русский ямб вы не уложитесь, общий ритм стиха нарушается.  Придумайте что-нибудь про бело-коричневую грудь))  Тогда все будет ОК.

@Sharon Можно убрать "если", хотел убрать, но всё же остановился на этом, чтоб выразить по возможности каждое английское слово.

Ну хорошо, лишь бы вам самому нравилось. Спасибо за участие!

Мне не очень нравится. А вам за раскачку, а то затишье и даже троллинг был.

Тогда исправите потом, когда будет вдохновение)  Это как?

Не понял, что "как"? Запал ушёл, и муза испарилась, тра-та, тра-тра, и я пропал опять...

Понятно. But you better not disappear...

@Sharon До сегодняшнего дня я вообще не читал Шекспира (отдельная благодарность вам!). // Пишу сказать о своей находке, как мне видится удачной. Оцените её, пжлст. У Шекспира повторяется слово "red", у двух переводчиков "краснее". Один "red" означает цвет/колоратуру, заменяю на "цвет", а сравнение выражено алым цветом, как передающим значение "намного краснее". "Алее" – это и есть уже "превосходнее" просто красного.

И правда круто!  Или "имба" (я так научилась говорить).  Но вы же в оттенках разбираетесь! Кому как не вам это заметить,  Теперь совсем близко к оригиналу.  // А мне Буратино песенку прислал. Посмотрите чуть ниже. //  Да я сама в Шекспира погрузилась не так давно. Книгу вот смотрю: Елизаветинская Англия. Путешествие во времени. Почему-то все интересно. А всё Шекспир!


Когда погружаешься в атмосферу Шекспира и понимаешь эту сверхзадачу,
то невольно возникает мысль: а что если попробовать перевести сонет?
Ну хотя бы не весь, а одно четверостишье... Может быть, так можно
попасть в творческую мастерскую Маршака.

Попытался перевести первые четыре строки:
My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun;
Coral is far more red than her lips' red;
If snow be white, why then her breasts are dun;
If hairs be wires, black wires grow on her head.
I have seen roses damask'd, red and white,
But no such roses see I in her cheeks;
And in some perfumes is there more delight
Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks.
I love to hear her speak, yet well I know
That music hath a far more pleasing sound;
I grant I never saw a goddess go;
My mistress, when she walks, treads on the
ground:
And yet, by heaven, I think my love as rare
As any she belied with false compare.

Результат:
Глаза моей любимой — совсем не солнца свет;
Коралл гораздо краснее её губ;
Вокруг белый снег, но её груди бурый цвет;
Волосы — проволока, их у неё чёрный чуб.

Для сравнения прилагаю перевод Маршака:
Ее глаза на звезды не похожи,
Нельзя уста кораллами назвать,
Не белоснежна плеч открытых кожа,
И черной проволокой вьется прядь.

С дамасской розой, алой или белой,
Нельзя сравнить оттенок этих щек.
А тело пахнет так, как пахнет тело,
Не как фиалки нежный лепесток.

Ты не найдешь в ней совершенных линий,
Особенного света на челе.
Не знаю я, как шествуют богини,
Но милая ступает по земле.

И все ж она уступит тем едва ли,
Кого в сравненьях пышных оболгали.

Итак, вопросы:

Могу еще КОНКРЕТНЕЕ: Каковы достоинства и недостатки переводов
Маршака? Как сохранить одно и уйти от другого? Или нужно нечто совсем
новое, чтобы поразить русского читателя?

Каковы достоинства и недостатки переводов Маршака?
Достоинства
Маршак хорошо адаптировал сонет под русского читателя; в большинстве строк отлично передан смысл.

Недостатки
Маршак весьма своеобразно трактует оригинал, оттого его работа самобытна. В ней смягчён тон; потеряна уникальная ритмика; используются совсем другие образы.

Сопоставление отдельных строк для наглядности
My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun
Coral is far more red than her lips' red
И
Ее глаза на звезды не похожи
Нельзя уста кораллами назвать

And in some perfumes is there more delight
Than in the breath that from my mistress reeks
И
А тело пахнет так, как пахнет тело
Не как фиалки нежный лепесток

If snow be white, why then her breasts are dun
If hairs be wires, black wires grow on her head
И
Не белоснежна плеч открытых кожа,
И черной проволокой вьется прядь.

Как сохранить одно и уйти от другого?
Никак: перевод всегда будет отличаться от оригинала, как бы ни хотел переводчик передать именно тот смысл, который вкладывал поэт. Связано это с языковыми различиями (существуют непереводимые фразы; одинаковые слова имеют разное количество слогов, что принципиально для стихов, и т. д.) и с временными различиями (в древних текстах используется архаичная лексика, к которой иногда невозможно подобрать аналоги; в древних текстах могут использоваться устаревшие правила и т. д.). В любом случае несостыковок будет множество.
Или нужно нечто совсем новое, чтобы поразить русского читателя?
За всех тяжело утверждать, потому буду говорить только за себя: меня бы удивил перевод, в котором после каждого четверостишия обращаются к оригиналу и объясняют, почему были избраны именно такие обороты и методы стихосложения (так легко понять, каким образом мыслил переводчик во время работы и "правильно" ли он вообще понял стих). Конечно, тут не обойтись и без ремарок по поводу различий между временами и вообще любых отличий, которые могли бы воспрепятствовать правильному восприятию. Иными словами, работа должна выставлять напоказ изнанку не только оригинала, но и свою, причем расписанную подробно, а не парой строк.
Такая работа, по моему мнению, была бы монументальной.

Спасибо за внимание к теме, голос от меня.  Ближе  к тексту — да, но у Маршака, пожалуй, лучше)

У Маршака тоническое стихосложение, соревноваться с ним в этом плане сложно.  Попробуйте уложить в четырехстопный ямб шекспировские фразы. Но даже если это получится, то еще не факт, что это будет стих, а не рифмованная проза. Нужна особая поэтика стиха, кисть художника. Это как в живописи: вроде похоже на реальное изображение, а не трогает, нет в нем живой души.

Но вы все равно попробуйте. Интересно!

Я в этом не силён, но попробовал:
Глаза моей любимой — совсем не солнца свет,
И губы не краснее алого коралла,
И вместо грудей белоснежных виден бурый цвет;
И волосы, как проволоку, зажевало.
:D
Не даётся мне последняя строка совсем

Оригинальный перевод!  С последней строкой, пожалуй, не соглашусь. Если волосы - проволока, то черная проволока растет на ее голове. Почему зажевало. // Вообще  к этой проволоке вопросы - может, это жесткие кудри?  Древнеанглийский wir "металл, вытянутый в тонкую нить", от протогерманского * wira- (источник также древнескандинавского viravirka "филигранная работа", шведского vira "скручивать", древневерхненемецкого wiara "тонкая золотая работа"), от корня ПИРОГА * wei- "крутить, скручивать, заплетать".

Откуда у Шекспира проволока, когда она вообще появилась?

Очень давно... издревле используется для украшений

Комментарий к ответу @Арчи
ДИАЛОГ

Спасибо вам за новую редакцию ответа и за внимание к теме.

Прошла всего неделя, но мой взгляд на сонеты Шекспира изменился кардинально. Сейчас  я считаю, что поэт и переводчик должны выступать как соавторы, если это действительно достойный художественный перевод.
Как я теперь думаю, Маршак  выглядит слишком простым, прозрачным, в нем мало глубины. Там как бы обозначена граница, за которую мы не заходим, и в  этих пределах воспринимаем Шекспира,  размышляем  о тех предметах, про которых он говорит.
Но за чертой оказывается огромное и недоступное нам пространство, terra incognita, о котором мы даже не подозреваем.  И если поэт-переводчик может хотя бы наметить  его, это уже огромное достижение.
Сонеты составляют циклы, в них должно быть движение мысли, развитие идеи и ее воплощения  в различных художественных образах. Но видим ли мы это в переводах Маршака? Обычно читатели помнят несколько сонетов, которые действительно выделяются среди других, но это все. Грандиозный театр английского драматурга, выраженный в 154 сонетах, остается непонятым и неисследованным в достаточной мере.
Вернее сказать, такое понимание может быть в научной среде, но до широких общественных масс оно не доходит. Как я думаю, мы до сих пор не знаем  ИСТИННОГО ШЕКСПИРА, его бурных страстей и настоящих переживаний, выраженных в его поэзии.

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ (материалы ресурса  https://studfile.net/preview/8673312/page:12/)

27.Сонеты Шекспира (темы, идеи, художественное своеобразие)
Соне́ты Уи́льяма Шекспи́ра — стихотворения Уильяма Шекспира, написанные в форме сонета. Всего их 154 и бо́льшая часть написана в 1592—1599 годах.
 Сонеты, посвящённые другу: 1—126
 Воспевание друга: 1—26
 Испытания дружбы: 27—99
 Горечь разлуки: 27—32
 Первое разочарование в друге: 33—42
 Тоска и опасения: 43—55
 Растущее отчуждение и меланхолия: 56—75
 Соперничество и ревность к другим поэтам: 76—96
 «Зима» разлуки: 97—99
 Торжество возобновлённой дружбы: 100—126
 Сонеты, посвящённые смуглой возлюбленной: 127—152
 Заключение — радость и красота любви: 153—154


Примечание. Это условная классификация.  К примеру, существование друга может быть понято как обращение поэта к своему духовному Я. Тогда мы воспринимаем сонеты с большим сочувствием, они будто обращены к каждому из нас.

И тогда это повод задуматься о том, как мы распоряжаемся нашей жизнью, на что тратим этот ДРАГОЦЕННЫЙ ДАР, полученный от Природы.

А что для вас Шекспир, какое место он занимает в вашей жизни, или это совсем не ваше? В первом цикле  поэт говорит о красоте человеческой души, 26 художественных картин  на одну тему. Какими красками пользуется художник слова, как строит каждую композицию?

Попробуйте все же зайти в эту удивительную галерею искусства, или же представьте сонеты в виде живой картины — в определенном цвете, в движении, с музыкой. Это и будет настоящим театром Шекспира.
Пожалуйста, расскажите о своих впечатлениях)
Все сонеты, удобный ресурс

О дословных или близких к оригиналу переводах
Быть ближе к Шекспиру не так просто, хотелось бы больше знать эту тему. Какие трудности можно встретить в этом случае? Рассмотрим, к примеру, сонет 141 Мои глаза в тебя не влюблены, http://velchel.ru/index.php?cnt=5&sn=141  Переводных вариантов здесь особенно много.

Трудности языка

Как уложить английскую речь  того времени в современную русскую грамматику?
Диалог из комментариев:
— Я бы второе четверостишье записала бы так (по грамматике)...
—  В общем, я пока не знаю, дело в том, что там нетипичная конструкция, НОР стоит вначале предложения, а последние утверждение через запятую вообще без НОР или какого-то отрицания. То есть это утвердительная конструкция. Про утвердительные конструкции с НОР пока мало нашёл информации, а так же про то, когда НОР идет вначале.) Короче вот такой он, староанглийский, все не так...

Понимание духовной жизни того времени

Золотой век Елизаветы (1558 — 1603). Совсем недалеко ушли от средневековья, но люди уже другие. Они полны достоинства и хотят видеть в себе личность, человека. Они много читают, размышляют, пишут стихи. У них определенное отношение к религии.
Что значит грешить в их понимании, насколько ни религиозны? Маршак довольно свободно толкует строки из сонета в этом плане, а как их понимал Шекспир?
 Who leaves unswayed the likeness of a man,
 Thy proud heart's slave and vassal wretch to be.
 Who leaves unswayed the likeness of a man,
 Thy proud heart's slave and vassal wretch to be.
 Only my plague thus far I count my gain,
 That she that makes me sin awards me pain.

Дословный перевод:
 Кто не оставляет сомнений в том, что он похож на человека, 
 Быть рабом и вассалом твоего гордого сердца - значит быть 
 несчастным.
 Пока что я считаю своим приобретением только чуму, 
 Та, кто заставляет меня ГРЕШИТЬ, награждает меня болью.


Почему не все сонеты Шекспира одинаково известны?

Не все 154 стиха являются шедеврами  в нашем понимании? Но почему? Сам поэт был недостаточно точен и подобрал не единственно правильные слова? Изменилась наша интерпретация его идей?
Что служит препятствием для создания совершенного художественного образа при переводе?  Так или иначе, но мы воспринимаем конечный результат.  Вероятно, главное – это понимание духовности Шекспира, а не дословное следование оригинальному тексту.
Лучшие сонеты Шекспира

Who leaves unswayed the likeness of a man - кто остаётся неизменённым подобием человека. Остаётся подобием, но человеком быть не желает.

ЧТО Я ХОТЕЛА БЫ УВИДЕТЬ В ПЕРЕВОДАХ МАРШАКА (идеи для новых переводов)

Моя основная художественная концепция такая: искусное смешение РАЗНОГО будоражит чувства при восприятии стиха (или песни) и поэтому нравится.

Это часто можно видеть у Пушкина:  Вот бегает дворовый мальчик, В салазки жучку посадив, Себя в коня преобразив (здесь лексика разных стилей).
При переводе сонетов я это представляю так: правильная  русская современная грамматика и размер стиха  + лексика, фразеология, метафоры, взятые  из текстов Шекспира 16-го века. Лексика должна быть в центре внимания на безупречном грамматическом фоне, то есть это опорные/ключевые слова при восприятии текста.

Желательна определенная недосказанность и многозначность смысла, а иначе слишком понятный текст становится скучным.

Существует стилевое и смысловое несоответствие некоторых слов  с тематикой Шекспира,  так что они царапают слух и привлекают к себе ненужное внимание. Такие слова лучше избегать. Мне, к примеру, не нравятся «черви» (очень грубо) и  «вдова»  (не особо современная характеристика  женщины), да еще при многократном повторе.

О дословности перевода.  Соответствие оригиналу желательно, но дословность не должна быть самоцелью. При необходимости лучше уйти от нее, чем строить стих только на соответствии.


Возьмем, к примеру, сонет 66.  Маршак при переводе оставляет  смысловое содержание оригинала, но лексику берет свою. Композиция построена на противопоставлении, но она слишком  однообразна и ожидаема.   Лексика абстрактная, а конкретики и образности немного, но ведь все это есть у Шекспира.  Прекрасный стих у Маршака, но все-таки новый перевод может быть не хуже, а в чем-то и лучше.

"Маршак при переводе оставляет смысловое содержание оригинала" - так не же) Черви там именно они, можно попробовать сделать змей, но там вроде черви) и вдовы, а не кто-то ещё.

СОРЕВНОВАНИЕ!
Шекспир — Её глаза на звезды не похожи — Сонет 130:
 Ее глаза на звезды не похожи
 Нельзя уста кораллами назвать,
 Не белоснежна плеч открытых кожа,
 И черной проволокой вьется прядь.

Как  солнце не сияет ее взгляд,
И снег куда белее смуглой кожи,
Волнами  кудри жесткие лежат,
А губы на  кораллы не похожи.
Предлагайте варианты))

@Буратино  А вы не могли бы перевести это четверостишье, пжста?  Близко к оригиналу.  Очень интересно сравнить)  Поучительно и познавательно.

Принимайте перевод)

и даже песенку: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/tMQWEw8fJqh92Q )

Восхитительно, да! Над переводом я еще собиралась задуматься, но песенка решила всё! Настоящий Шекспир!  Будто его слышу. Это не Бернс через 200 лет:  Был мягок шелк ее волос . Там еще средневековье недалече.  Спасибо тысячу раз! Буду слушать и слушать!

ХОТИТЕ НАЙТИ В ШЕКСПИРЕ ЧТО-ТО НОВОЕ?
Это я обращаюсь к тем, кому он не очень интересен. Так хотите попробовать?
Вот сонет 66 в переводе Маршака, он мне всегда особенно нравился.
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/2917971335252384527
 Зову я смерть. Мне видеть невтерпеж
 Достоинство, что просит подаянья,
 Над простотой глумящуюся ложь,
 Ничтожество в роскошном одеянье,
 И совершенству ложный приговор,
 И девственность, поруганную грубо,
 И неуместной почести позор,
 И мощь в плену у немощи беззубой,
 И прямоту, что глупостью слывет,
 И глупость в маске мудреца, пророка,
 И вдохновения зажатый рот,
 И праведность на службе у порока.

 Все мерзостно, что вижу я вокруг...
 Но как тебя покинуть, милый друг!

Еще бы!  Смотришь на мир со стороны и думаешь: «Как же у них тут всё плохо! Сколько недостатков,  разве можно быть такими! Вот я-то совсем другой».
А теперь попробуйте отнести это все к себе.  Каждую строчку! Это не про них, а про Тебя.
Ну и как? Получилось? И остального Шекспира (сонеты 1 — 127, посвященные "прекрасному другу"), читайте так же. Тогда будет интересно!
Тема сонетов 27—99: Испытание дружбой. Растущее отчуждение и меланхолия: 56—75
